# Can you provide examples of parsing HTML?

Tags: html, language-agnostic, html-parsing

How do you parse HTML with a variety of languages and parsing libraries?

---

When answering:

Individual comments will be linked to in answers to questions about how to parse HTML with regexes as a way of showing the right way to do things.

For the sake of consistency, I ask that the example be parsing an HTML file for the `href` in anchor tags. To make it easy to search this question, I ask that you follow this format

Language: [language name]

Library: [library name]

```
[example code]
```

Please make the library a link to the documentation for the library. If you want to provide an example other than extracting links, please also include:

Purpose: [what the parse does]

Comment: repeat for each example the HTML builder code is pointless

Comment: and why you are clutting perl code with pointless/useless use directives? (warnings and strict)

Comment: Self contained, working examples are better.  All Perl code should include strict and warnings, they are not pointless; they are a part of Modern Perl.  I shudder to think what your code looks like if you think they are "pointless" and "useless".

Comment: in my code I always use warnings and strict; in *THIS* context they are pointless. Most of this samples are not "self contained" (e.g. jquery, ruby and other answers) so why bother with perl-based solutions?

Comment: Because you can, and the JavaScript examples are self contained in their environment.  I haven't changed the nokogiri example because I can't get nokogiri to install on my machine.  I don't want to change code I don't understand.  But I will change it; for one thing it doesn't look like it is solving the example.  As for using strict, modeling unsafe code for people who are learning is a crime.  They need all of the reinforcement they can get.

Comment: you are adding distracting things; use strict and resource handling is not the central point of the question

Comment: @Ira Baxter What part of "This question is a lazy way of collecting examples of parsing HTML with a variety of languages and parsing libraries." did you not understand?

Comment: C and C++ are tagged, but have no any example here. :(

Comment: @Jack Yes, they are tagged so someone will **provide** an example.

Answer (score 29):

Language: [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
Library: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$.each($('a[href]'), function(){
    console.debug(this.href);
});
```

(using firebug console.debug for output...)

And loading any html page:

```
$.get('http://stackoverflow.com/', function(page){
     $(page).find('a[href]').each(function(){
        console.debug(this.href);
    });
});
```

Used another each function for this one, I think it's cleaner when chaining methods.

Comment: Well yes, if you look at it that way. :)  
But using javascript/jquery for parsing HTML feels very natural, it's perfect for stuff like this.

Comment: Using the browser as the parser is the ultimate parser.  The DOM in a given browser *is* the document tree.

Answer (score 25):

Language: C#
Library: [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

language: Python
library: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = "<html><body>"
for link in ("foo", "bar", "baz"):
    html += '<a href="http://%s.com">%s</a>' % (link, link)
html += "</body></html>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.findAll('a', href=True) # find <a> with a defined href attribute
print links
```

output:

```
[<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>,
 <a href="http://bar.com">bar</a>,
 <a href="http://baz.com">baz</a>]
```

also possible:

```
for link in links:
    print link['href']
```

output:

```
http://foo.com
http://bar.com
http://baz.com
```

Comment: This is nice, but does BeautifulSoup provide a way of looking into the tags to get the attributes? *goes off to look at docs*

Comment: The output in the first example is just the text representation of the matched links, they are actually objects to which you can do all kinds of fun stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I just read the docs, you just beat me to fixing the code.  I did add the try/catch to prevent it from blowing up when href isn't there though.  Apparently "'href' in link" doesn't work.

Answer (score 20):

Language: Perl
Library: [pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/dist/pQuery/)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use pQuery;

my $html = join '',
    "<html><body>",
    (map { qq(<a href="http://$_.com">$_</a>) } qw/foo bar baz/),
    "</body></html>";

pQuery( $html )->find( 'a' )->each(
    sub {  
        my $at = $_->getAttribute( 'href' ); 
        print "$at\n" if defined $at;
    }
);
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Never knew about pQuery, but it looks very cool.

Comment: Can you search for 'a[@href]' or 'a[href]' as in jQuery? It would simplify the code, and quite sure be faster.

Comment: Here are some other stackoverflow questions with pQuery answers...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713827/how-can-i-screen-scrape-with-perl/713846#713846    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574199/how-do-i-extract-an-html-title-with-perl    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-urls-from-a-web-page-in-perl/254506#254506   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221091/how-can-i-extract-xml-of-a-website-and-save-in-a-file-using-perls-lwp/223662#223662

Comment: @code-is-art:  Unfortunately not yet... to quote author from docs "The selector syntax is still very limited. (Single tags, IDs and classes only)".  Checkout the tests because pQuery does have features that aren't in the documentation, for eg. say 'Number of <td> with "blah" content - ', pQuery('td:contains(blah)')->size;

Answer (score 15):

language: shell
library: [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.6/lynx2-8-6/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html) (well, it's not library, but in shell, every program is kind-of library)

```
lynx -dump -listonly http://news.google.com/
```

Comment: +1 for trying, +1 for a working solution, -1 for the solution not being generalizable to other tasks: net +1

Comment: well, the task was quite well defined - it had to extract links from "a" tags. :)

Comment: Yes, but it is defined as an example to show how to parse, I could have just as easily asked you to print all of the contents of <td> tags that had the class "phonenum".

Comment: I agree that this doesn't help with the generic question, but the specific question is likely to be a popular one, so it seems reasonable to me as a way to do it for a specific domain of the general problem.

Answer (score 14):

language: Ruby
library: [Hpricot](http://wiki.github.com/why/hpricot/an-hpricot-showcase)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'hpricot'

html = '<html><body>'
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].each {|link| html += "<a href=\"http://#{link}.com\">#{link}</a>" }
html += '</body></html>'

doc = Hpricot(html)
doc.search('//a').each {|elm| puts elm.attributes['href'] }
```

Answer (score 12):

language: Python
library: [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class FindLinks(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        at = dict(attrs)
        if tag == 'a' and 'href' in at:
            print at['href']


find = FindLinks()

html = "<html><body>"
for link in ("foo", "bar", "baz"):
    html += '<a href="http://%s.com">%s</a>' % (link, link)
html += "</body></html>"

find.feed(html)
```

Answer (score 11):

language: Perl
library: [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;

my $find_links = HTML::Parser->new(
    start_h => [
        sub {
            my ($tag, $attr) = @_;
            if ($tag eq 'a' and exists $attr->{href}) {
                print "$attr->{href}\n";
            }
        }, 
        "tag, attr"
    ]
);

my $html = join '',
    "<html><body>",
    (map { qq(<a href="http://$_.com">$_</a>) } qw/foo bar baz/),
    "</body></html>";

$find_links->parse($html);
```

Comment: Using LWP::Simple to download this page (as I do below in my perl example) showed that you found a's that didn't have href's (but had names), so we just want to check that there *is* an href before printing it.

Answer (score 9):

Language Perl
Library: [HTML::LinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.60/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm)

Beauty of Perl is that you have modules for very specific tasks. Like link extraction.

Whole program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use HTML::LinkExtor;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url     = 'http://www.google.com/';
my $content = get( $url );

my $p       = HTML::LinkExtor->new( \&process_link, $url, );
$p->parse( $content );

exit;

sub process_link {
    my ( $tag, %attr ) = @_;

    return unless $tag eq 'a';
    return unless defined $attr{ 'href' };

    print "- $attr{'href'}\n";
    return;
}
```

Explanation:

- use strict - turns on "strict" mode -
  eases potential debugging, not fully
  relevant to the example
- use HTML::LinkExtor - load of interesting module
- use LWP::Simple - just a simple way to get some html for tests
- my $url = 'http://www.google.com/' - which page we will be extracting urls from
- my $content = get( $url ) - fetches page html
- my $p = HTML::LinkExtor->new( \&process_link, $url ) - creates LinkExtor object, givin it reference to function that will be used as callback on every url, and $url to use as BASEURL for relative urls
- $p->parse( $content ) - pretty obvious I guess
- exit - end of program
- sub process_link - begin of function process_link
- my ($tag, %attr) - get arguments, which are tag name, and its atributes
- return unless $tag eq 'a' - skip processing if the tag is not <a>
- return unless defeined $attr{'href'} - skip processing if the <a> tag doesn't have href attribute
- print "- $attr{'href'}\n"; - pretty obvious I guess :)
- return; - finish the function

That's all.

Comment: Nice, but I think you are missing the point of the question, the example is there so that the code will be similar, not because I want the links.  Think in more general terms.  The goal is to provide people with the tools to use parsers instead of regexes.

Comment: It is possible that I miss something, but I read in the problem description: "For the sake of consistency, I ask that the example be parsing an HTML file for the href in anchor tags." If you'd ask for example of parsing <td> tags - I would probably use HTML::TableExtract - basically - specialized tool beats (in my opinion) general tool.

Comment: Fine, find all span tags that have the class "to_understand_intent" that are inside of div tags whose class is "learn".  Specialized tools are great, but they are just that: specialized.  You will wind up needing to know the general tool one day.  This is a question about the general tools, not specialized libraries that use those tools.

Comment: For this new request - of course HTML::Parser would be much better. But just saying "use HTML::Parser" is plain wrong. One should use proper tool for a given task. For extracting hrefs I would say that using HTML::Parser is overkill. For extracting <td>s - as well. Asking "give me general way to parse ..." is wrong because it assumes that there exists 1 tool (in language) that's perfect for all cases. I personally parse HTML in at least 6 different ways, depending on what I need to do.

Comment: Look at the task again.  The task was not get the links in an HTMl page, it was demonstrate how your favorite parser works using getting the links in an HTML page as an example.  It was chosen because it is a simple task that involves finding the right tag and looking at a piece of data in it.  It was also chosen because it is a common task.  Because it is a common task Perl has automated it for you, but that doesn't mean this question was asking for you to give the automated answer.

Comment: @Chas. Owens: the task was specific; given that a solution exists on CPAN, there should be an example using it (as well as a more general HTML::Parser example).  And it isn't fully automated; you have to filter it to just anchor tag href attributes - how to do so is worth showing in an example.

Comment: Shorter:  HTML::LinkExtor->new( sub{ print $_[2] if $_[0] eq "a" } )->parse_file("sample.html")

Comment: @ysth, the task was chose at random, I could have chosen anything.  As I have stated several times, the purpose of this question is to collect examples of full parsers, not to solve the example with specialized libraries that use parsers.  This answer would be fine if the question was "How do I extract links from HTML with Perl?", but the question is "Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?"; therefore the task is demonstrate a parser, not extract links.

Answer (score 8):

Language: Ruby
Library: [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

document = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://google.com"))
document.css("html head title").first.content
=> "Google"
document.xpath("//title").first.content
=> "Google"
```

Answer (score 8):

Language: Common Lisp
Library: [Closure Html](http://common-lisp.net/project/closure/closure-html), [Closure Xml](http://common-lisp.net/project/cxml/), [CL-WHO](http://www.weitz.de/cl-who/)

(shown using DOM API, without using XPATH or STP API)

```
(defvar *html*
  (who:with-html-output-to-string (stream)
    (:html
     (:body (loop
               for site in (list "foo" "bar" "baz")
               do (who:htm (:a :href (format nil "http://~A.com/" site))))))))

(defvar *dom*
  (chtml:parse *html* (cxml-dom:make-dom-builder)))

(loop
   for tag across (dom:get-elements-by-tag-name *dom* "a")
   collect (dom:get-attribute tag "href"))
=> 
("http://foo.com/" "http://bar.com/" "http://baz.com/")
```

Comment: does collect or dom:get-attribute correctly handle tags that do not have href set?

Comment: Depending on definition of correctness. In example as it is shown, empty strings will be collected for "a" tags with no "href" attribute.
If loop is rewritten as
(loop
   for tag across (dom:get-elements-by-tag-name *dom* "a")
   when (string/= (dom:get-attribute tag "href") "")
   collect (dom:get-attribute tag "href"))
then only non-empty "href"s will be collected.

Comment: Actually, that's not
   when (string/= (dom:get-attribute tag "href") "")
but
   when (dom:has-attribute tag "href")

Comment: How would you do that without the loop macro?

Answer (score 6):

Language: [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)
Library:  [Enlive](http://github.com/cgrand/enlive/) (a selector-based (à la CSS) templating and transformation system for Clojure)

---

Selector expression:

```
(def test-select
     (html/select (html/html-resource (java.io.StringReader. test-html)) [:a]))
```

Now we can do the following at the REPL (I've added line breaks in `test-select`):

```
user> test-select
({:tag :a, :attrs {:href "http://foo.com/"}, :content ["foo"]}
 {:tag :a, :attrs {:href "http://bar.com/"}, :content ["bar"]}
 {:tag :a, :attrs {:href "http://baz.com/"}, :content ["baz"]})
user> (map #(get-in % [:attrs :href]) test-select)
("http://foo.com/" "http://bar.com/" "http://baz.com/")
```

---

You'll need the following to try it out:

Preamble:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
```

Test HTML:

```
(def test-html
     (apply str (concat ["<html><body>"]
                        (for [link ["foo" "bar" "baz"]]
                          (str "<a href=\"http://" link ".com/\">" link "</a>"))
                        ["</body></html>"])))
```

Comment: Not sure if I'd call Enlive a "parser", but I'd certainly use it in place of one, so -- here's an example.

Answer (score 5):

language: Perl
library: [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode ':all';

use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Twig;

#my $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser';
my $url = 'http://www.google.com';
my $content = get($url);
die "Couldn't fetch!" unless defined $content;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
$twig->parse_html($content);

my @hrefs = map {
    $_->att('href');
} $twig->get_xpath('//*[@href]');

print "$_\n" for @hrefs;
```

caveat: Can get wide-character errors with pages like this one (changing the url to the one commented out will get this error), but the HTML::Parser solution above doesn't share this problem.

Comment: Nice, I use XML::Twig all the time and never realized there was a parse_html method.

Answer (score 5):

Language: Perl
Library: [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm)
Purpose: [How can I remove unused, nested HTML span tags with a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667130/how-can-i-remove-unused-nested-html-span-tags-with-a-perl-regex/667425#667425)

Answer (score 5):

Language: Java
Libraries: [XOM](http://www.xom.nu), [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)

I've included intentionally malformed and inconsistent XML in this sample.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import nu.xom.Builder;
import nu.xom.Document;
import nu.xom.Element;
import nu.xom.Node;
import nu.xom.Nodes;
import nu.xom.ParsingException;
import nu.xom.ValidityException;

import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class HtmlTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws SAXException, ValidityException, ParsingException, IOException {
        final Parser parser = new Parser();
        parser.setFeature(Parser.namespacesFeature, false);
        final Builder builder = new Builder(parser);
        final Document document = builder.build("<html><body><ul><li><a href=\"http://google.com\">google</li><li><a HREF=\"http://reddit.org\" target=\"_blank\">reddit</a></li><li><a name=\"nothing\">nothing</a><li></ul></body></html>", null);
        final Element root = document.getRootElement();
        final Nodes links = root.query("//a[@href]");
        for (int linkNumber = 0; linkNumber < links.size(); ++linkNumber) {
            final Node node = links.get(linkNumber);
            System.out.println(((Element) node).getAttributeValue("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

TagSoup adds an XML namespace referencing XHTML to the document by default. I've chosen to suppress that in this sample. Using the default behavior would require the call to `root.query` to include a namespace like so:

```
root.query("//xhtml:a[@href]", new nu.xom.XPathContext("xhtml", root.getNamespaceURI())
```

Comment: I'm sure either will work fine. TagSoup was made to parse whatever you can throw at it.

Answer (score 4):

Language: [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
Library: [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)

```
var links = document.links;
for(var i in links){
    var href = links[i].href;
    if(href != null) console.debug(href);
}
```

(using firebug console.debug for output...)

Answer (score 4):

Language: C#
Library: [System.XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml(VS.80).aspx) (standard .NET)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> matches = new List<string>();

    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXml("<html>...</html>");

    FindHrefs(xd.FirstChild, matches);
}

static void FindHrefs(XmlNode xn, List<string> matches)
{
    if (xn.Attributes != null && xn.Attributes["href"] != null)
        matches.Add(xn.Attributes["href"].InnerXml);

    foreach (XmlNode child in xn.ChildNodes)
        FindHrefs(child, matches);
}
```

Comment: will this work if the HTML is not valid xml (e.g. unclosed img tags)?

Answer (score 4):

Language: PHP
Library: [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) (and DOM)

```
<?php
$page = new DOMDocument();
$page->strictErrorChecking = false;
$page->loadHTMLFile('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($page);

$links = $xml->xpath('//a[@href]');
foreach($links as $link)
    echo $link['href']."\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Language: [Racket](http://racket-lang.org)

Library: [(planet ashinn/html-parser:1)](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=html-parser.plt&owner=ashinn) and [(planet clements/sxml2:1)](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=sxml2.plt&owner=clements)

```
(require net/url
         (planet ashinn/html-parser:1)
         (planet clements/sxml2:1))

(define the-url (string->url "http://stackoverflow.com/"))
(define doc (call/input-url the-url get-pure-port html->sxml))
(define links ((sxpath "//a/@href/text()") doc))
```

Above example using packages from the new package system: [html-parsing](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=sxml2.plt&owner=clements) and [sxml](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=sxml2.plt&owner=clements)

```
(require net/url
         html-parsing
         sxml)

(define the-url (string->url "http://stackoverflow.com/"))
(define doc (call/input-url the-url get-pure-port html->xexp))
(define links ((sxpath "//a/@href/text()") doc))
```

Note: Install the required packages with 'raco' from a command line, with:

```
raco pkg install html-parsing
```

and:

```
raco pkg install sxml
```

Answer (score 3):

language: Python
library: [lxml.html](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html)

```
import lxml.html

html = "<html><body>"
for link in ("foo", "bar", "baz"):
    html += '<a href="http://%s.com">%s</a>' % (link, link)
html += "</body></html>"

tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
for element, attribute, link, pos in tree.iterlinks():
    if attribute == "href":
        print link
```

lxml also has a CSS selector class for traversing the DOM, which can make using it very similar to using JQuery:

```
for a in tree.cssselect('a[href]'):
    print a.get('href')
```

Comment: Hmm, I am getting "ImportError: No module named html" when I try to run this, is there something I need besides python-lxml?

Comment: Ah, I have version 1.3.6 and that comes with 2.0 and later

Comment: Indeed. I can provide an example of using lxml.etree to do the job as well if you like? lxml.html is a bit more tolerant of broken HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Language: Perl
Library : [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/)

```
use strict;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use LWP::Simple;

my $content = get 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
my $document = HTML::TreeBuilder->new->parse($content)->eof;

for my $a ($document->find('a')) {
    print $a->attr('href'), "\n" if $a->attr('href');
}
```

Comment: It was also incorrect, you must call $document->eof; if you use $document->parse($html); and would print empty lines when href wasn't set.

Comment: reverted to my original code; ->eof() is useless in this sample; also checking for href presence is pointless in this example

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use new_from_content?

Answer (score 3):

Language: [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)
Library: [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) + [Matt Gallagher's libxml2 wrappers](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) + [Ben Copsey's ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest-CFNetwork-wrapper-for-HTTP-requests)

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340"];
[request start];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSData *response = [request responseData];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", [[self query:@"//a[@href]" withResponse:response] description]);
    [request release];
}
else 
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"kMyHTTPRequestFailed" reason:@"Request failed!" userInfo:nil];

...

- (id) query:(NSString *)xpathQuery WithResponse:(NSData *)resp {
    NSArray *nodes = PerformHTMLXPathQuery(resp, xpathQuery);
    if (nodes != nil)
        return nodes;
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Language: PHP
Library: DOM

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$links = $xpath->query('//a[@href]');
for ($i = 0; $i < $links->length; $i++)
    echo $links->item($i)->getAttribute('href'), "\n";
```

Sometimes it's useful to put `@` symbol before `$doc->loadHTMLFile` to suppress invalid html parsing warnings

Comment: Almost identical to my PHP version ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/774853#774853 ) You don't need the getAttribute call

Answer (score 1):

Language: [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python)
Library: [HTQL](http://htql.net/)

```
import htql; 

page="<a href=a.html>1</a><a href=b.html>2</a><a href=c.html>3</a>";
query="<a>:href,tx";

for url, text in htql.HTQL(page, query): 
    print url, text;
```

Simple and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Language: Java
Library: [jsoup](http://jsoup.org)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class HtmlTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws SAXException, ValidityException, ParsingException, IOException {
        final Document document = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><ul><li><a href=\"http://google.com\">google</li><li><a HREF=\"http://reddit.org\" target=\"_blank\">reddit</a></li><li><a name=\"nothing\">nothing</a><li></ul></body></html>");
        final Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
        for (final Element element : links) {
            System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

language: Ruby
library: [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))
hrefs = doc.search('a').map{ |n| n['href'] }

puts hrefs
```

Which outputs:

```
/
/domains/
/numbers/
/protocols/
/about/
/go/rfc2606
/about/
/about/presentations/
/about/performance/
/reports/
/domains/
/domains/root/
/domains/int/
/domains/arpa/
/domains/idn-tables/
/protocols/
/numbers/
/abuse/
http://www.icann.org/
mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback
```

---

This is a minor spin on the one above, resulting in an output that is usable for a report. I only return the first and last elements in the list of hrefs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://nokogiri.org'))
hrefs = doc.search('a[href]').map{ |n| n['href'] }

puts hrefs
  .each_with_index                     # add an array index
  .minmax{ |a,b| a.last <=> b.last }   # find the first and last element
  .map{ |h,i| '%3d %s' % [1 + i, h ] } # format the output

  1 http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri
100 http://yokolet.blogspot.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using phantomjs, save this file as extract-links.js:

```
var page = new WebPage(),
    url = 'http://www.udacity.com';

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var results = page.evaluate(function() {
            var list = document.querySelectorAll('a'), links = [], i;
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                links.push(list[i].href);
            }
            return links;
        });
        console.log(results.join('\n'));
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

run:

```
$ ../path/to/bin/phantomjs extract-links.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Language: Coldfusion 9.0.1+

Library:  [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

```
<cfscript>
function parseURL(required string url){
var res = [];
var javaLoader = createObject("javaloader.JavaLoader").init([expandPath("./jsoup-1.7.3.jar")]);
var jSoupClass = javaLoader.create("org.jsoup.Jsoup");
//var dom = jSoupClass.parse(html); // if you already have some html to parse.
var dom = jSoupClass.connect( arguments.url ).get();
var links = dom.select("a");
for(var a=1;a LT arrayLen(links);a++){
    var s={};s.href= links[a].attr('href'); s.text= links[a].text(); 
    if(s.href contains "http://" || s.href contains "https://") arrayAppend(res,s); 
}
return res; 
}   

//writeoutput(writedump(parseURL(url)));
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#parseURL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-examples-of-parsing-html")#">
```

Returns an array of structures, each struct contains an HREF and TEXT objects.

Answer (score 0):

Language: JavaScript/Node.js

Library: [Request](https://github.com/request/request) and [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "https://news.ycombinator.com/";
request(url, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var anchorTags = $('a');

        anchorTags.each(function(i,element){
            console.log(element["attribs"]["href"]);
        });
    }
});
```

Request library downloads the html document and Cheerio lets you use jquery css selectors to target the html document.