# How to write a regular expression for html parsing?

Tags: c++, html, regex, boost, html-content-extraction

I'm trying to write a regular expression for my html parser.

I want to match a html tag with given attribute (eg. `<div>` with `class="tab news selected"` ) that contains one or more `<a href>` tags. The regexp should match the entire tag (from `<div>` to `</div>`). I always seem to get "memory exhausted" errors - my program probably takes every tag it can find as a matching one.

I'm using boost regex libraries.

Comment: [Beware of Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135078)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also find these questions helpful:

[Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

[Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser)

Answer (score 7):

You should probably look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) re. regexps and HTML. The gist is that using regular expressions to parse HTML is not by any means an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, don't use regexes if at all possible. If your code is actually XHTML (i.e. it is also well-formed XML) aI can recommend both the [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) and [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) XML parsers, which will do a much betterv job for you than regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe regexps aren't the best solution, but I'm already using like five different libraries and boost does fine when it comes to locating `<a href>` tags and keywords.

I'm using these regexps:

`/<a[^\n]*/searched attribute/[^\n]*>[^\n]*</a>/` for locating `<a href>` tags and:

`/<a[^\n]*href[[^\n]*>/searched keyword/</a>/` for locating links

(BTW can it be done better? - I suck at regex ;))

What I need now is locating tags containing `<a href>`'s and I think regexps will do all right - maybe I'll need to write my own parsing function as piotr said.

Comment: It's not that regular expressions are not the best solution - for what you're trying to do regex is not a valid solution *at all*. Use a HTML or XML parser instead.

Comment: Ok, so which one do you recommend. I'd prefer an easy one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do as flex does: match <div> with a case insensitive match, and put your parser in a "div matched" state, keep processing input until </div> and reset state.

This takes two regexps and a state variable.

SGML tags valid characters are [A-Za-z_:]

So: /<[A-Za-z_:]+>/ matches a tag.

Comment: Or, instead of re-inventing the wheel, use an existing parser which has already been written and will already deal with edge cases and so on.