# getting specific information from a website in android

Tags: android, web-applications, web

i want to write a program that gets the match dates from this link http://www.goal.com/en/teams/germany/148/fc-bayern-munich-news
and use it in my program i just want the dates and the matches how can i do this? in andorid

Answer (score 1):

I'd write an [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to display the data, which calls an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to connect to the site and download the HTML.  I'd then use some kind of parser to grab the data I want and save it to a [database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Have you written Java before?  If not I'd start out by learning the language.  Download Eclipse and write a simple program that can connect to the site and grab the HTML.  Then add the parser.

Once you are that far, do the [Hello World](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html) tutorial, then work your way through the other tutorials.  Also learn about the Android [Application Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).  At that point you can start thinking about moving your code over to the Android framework.

**EDIT**
Here are some links to information about potential parsers & parsing approaches.

- [Tag Soup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)
- [What HTML parsing libraries do you recommend in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26638/512958)
- [Two HTML parsing links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792679/need-help-writing-regular-expression-html-parsing/795151#795151)

You could also consider using (*hushed voice*) regex/pattern matching.

Comment: yes i have written java before and android before! but i dont know how to parse a html and retrieve exactly what i want (match dates)

Comment: tnx but i dont have so much time i need samples or even an exact answer for my problem