# How do I extract data from a web page with regexes?

Tags: php, regex, screen-scraping

I am writing a curl script for collecting information about some sex offenders, i have developed the script that is picking up links like given below:

[http://criminaljustice.state.ny.us/cgi/internet/nsor/...](http://criminaljustice.state.ny.us/cgi/internet/nsor/fortecgi?serviceName=WebNSOR&templateName=detail.htm&requestingHandler=WebNSORDetailHandler&ID=368343543) (snipped URL)

Now when we go on this link I want to get information under all the fields on this page like Offender Id:, last name etc. into my own variables. I am very weak in regex that is why I am here. Or is there another way?

Can anybody help me in doing that?

Answer (score 4):

[phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) is very nice for screen-scraping in PHP. It lets you access the DOM using the same methods jQuery has.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want regexes (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege), look for an HTML Parser for PHP.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/774853#774853) to [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with the previous poster about RegEx not being the right tool for the job.  If you just want a quick and dirty expression, here goes:

```
Offender Id:.*
.*&amp;nbsp;[0-9]*
```

NOTE: 
You must include the newline in this expression.  Also note that this is very fragile as it will break if the source that your are parsing changes much at all.