# regular expression to remove links

Tags: html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have a HTML page with

```
<a class="development" href="[variable content]">X</a>
```

The [variable content] is different in each place, the rest is the same.
What regexp will catch all of those links?
(Although I am not writing it here, I did try...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the non-greedy version:

```
<a class="development" href="(.*?)">X</a>
```

Comment: You're doing a capture that likely won't be used. Other than that, I dont't see much difference in using this or Gumbo's version.

Answer (score 5):

Try this regular expression:

```
<a class="development" href="[^"]*">X</a>
```

Comment: single-quoted attributes are also valid html. and, depending on the source, you can even have invalid html, by which point you're screwed.

Answer (score 4):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is generally a bad solution for HTML parsing, a topic which gets discussed every time a question like this is asked. For example, the  element could wrap onto another line, either as

```
<a class="development" 
  href="[variable content]">X</a>
```

or

```
<a class="development" href="[variable content]">X
</a>
```

What are you trying to achieve?

Using JQuery you could disable the links with:

```
$("a.development").onclick = function() { return false; }
```

or

```
$("a.development").attr("href", "#");
```

Comment: this solution would assume that Itay Moav is using the jquery library and that it's a client side parsing that he wishes to acheive

Comment: @vrish88: Correct. Thus the question "What are you trying to achieve?" and the comment "Using JQuery you could..."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that'll allow all sorts of evil to be put in the `href` attribute.

```
/<a class="development" href=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s<>]+)>.*?<\/a>/m
```

I'm also assuming `X` is going to be variable, so I added a non-greedy match there to handle it, and the `/m` means `.` matches line-breaks too.