# Getting alt tags with regex

Tags: regex

I am parsing some HTML source. Is there a regex script to find out whether alt tags in a html document are empty?

I want to see if the alt tags are empty or not.

Is regex suitable for this or should I use string manipulation in C#?

Comment: Is it me or is there a glut of the dreaded regexhtml question recently?

Comment: @annakata: There has been a rise in frequency, that's my feeling as well. On the other hand, there has been a rise in CSS/HTML questions in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the HTML and check tags, use the following link, it includes a C# library for parsing HTML tags, and you can loop through tags and get the number of tags: [Parsing HTML tags](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/10918_2230091_2).

Answer (score 0):

If this is valid XHTML, why do you need Regex at all? If you simply search for the string:

`alt=""`

... you should be able to find all empty `alt` tags.

In any case, it shouldn't be too complicated to construct a Regex for the search too, taking into account poorly written HTML markup (especially with spaces):

```
alt\s*=\s*"\s*"
```

Comment: What if 'alt=""' is part of normal text?

Comment: and double quote could be single quotes, there could even be no quotes if the HTML is really sloppy.

Comment: Yep, I'm well aware of these possibilities. The OP hasn't provided enough info for us to make an intelligent assumption.

Comment: Apologies. Yeah, that wouldn't be possible because of the above issues. However, it is possible to look for that tag as double and single quotes and also check for spaces beside the a (in alt) and " (closing quotation mark). Reading character-by-character would make this pretty easy.

I am now using WatiN to find alt tags, as it has the relevant methods. Parsing is an interesting topic, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it just looking at the page then CSS selectors might be better, assuming your browser supports the :not selector.

Install the [selectorgadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) bookmarklet. Activate it on your page and then put the following selector in the intput box and press enter.

```
img:not([alt])
```

If you are automating it, and have access to the DOM for the HTML you could use the same selector.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.