# How can I efficiently handle multiple Perl search/replace operations on the same string?

Tags: regex, perl, hash, substitution

So my Perl script basically takes a string and then tries to clean it up by doing multiple search and replaces on it, like so:

```
$text =~ s/<[^>]+>/ /g;
$text =~ s/\s+/ /g;
$text =~ s/[\(\{\[]\d+[\(\{\[]/ /g;
$text =~ s/\s+[<>]+\s+/\. /g;
$text =~ s/\s+/ /g;
$text =~ s/\.*\s*[\*|\#]+\s*([A-Z\"])/\. $1/g; # replace . **** Begin or . #### Begin or ) *The 
$text =~ s/\.\s*\([^\)]*\) ([A-Z])/\. $1/g; # . (blah blah) S... => . S...
```

As you can see, I'm dealing with nasty html and have to beat it into submission.

I'm hoping there is a simpler, aesthetically appealing way to do this.  I have about 50 lines that look just like what is above.

I have solved one version of this problem by using a hash where the key is the comment, and the hash is the reg expression, like so:

```
%rxcheck = (
        'time of day'=>'\d+:\d+', 
    'starts with capital letters then a capital word'=>'^([A-Z]+\s)+[A-Z][a-z]',
    'ends with a single capital letter'=>'\b[A-Z]\.'
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
 foreach my $key (keys %rxcheck) {
if($snippet =~ /$rxcheck{ $key }/g){ blah blah  }
 }
```

The problem comes up when I try my hand at a hash that where the key is the expression and  it points to what I want to replace it with... and there is a $1 or $2 in it.

```
%rxcheck2 = (
        '(\w) \"'=>'$1\"'
}
```

The above is to do this:

```
$snippet =~ s/(\w) \"/$1\"/g;
```

But I can't seem to pass the "$1" part into the regex literally (I think that's the right word... it seems the $1 is being interpreted even though I used ' marks.) So this results in:

```
if($snippet =~ /$key/$rxcheck2{ $key }/g){  }
```

And that doesn't work.

So 2 questions:

Easy: How do I handle large numbers of regex's in an easily editable way so I can change and add them without just cut and pasting the line before?

Harder: How do I handle them using a hash (or array if I have, say, multiple pieces I want to include, like 1) part to search, 2) replacement 3) comment, 4) global/case insensitive modifiers), if that is in fact the easiest way to do this?

Thanks for your help -

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Problem #1

As there doesn't appear to be much structure shared by the individual regexes, there's not really a simpler or clearer way than just listing the commands as you have done.  One common approach to decreasing repetition in code like this is to move `$text` into `$_`, so that instead of having to say:

```
$text =~ s/foo/bar/g;
```

You can just say:

```
s/foo/bar/g;
```

A common idiom for doing this is to use a degenerate `for()` loop as a topicalizer:

```
for($text)
{
  s/foo/bar/g;
  s/qux/meh/g;
  ...
}
```

The scope of this block will preserve any preexisting value of `$_`, so there's no need to explicitly `local`ize `$_`.

At this point, you've eliminated almost every non-boilerplate character -- how much shorter can it get, even in theory?

Unless what you really want (as your problem #2 suggests) is improved *modularity*, e.g., the ability to iterate over, report on, count etc. all regexes.

### Problem #2

You can use the `qr//` syntax to quote the "search" part of the substitution:

```
my $search = qr/(<[^>]+>)/;
$str =~ s/$search/foo,$1,bar/;
```

However I don't know of a way of quoting the "replacement" part adequately.  I had hoped that `qr//` would work for this too, but it doesn't.  There are two alternatives worth considering:

**1. Use `eval()` in your `foreach` loop.**  This would enable you to keep your current `%rxcheck2` hash.  Downside: you should always be concerned about safety with string `eval()`s.

**2. Use an array of anonymous subroutines:**

```
my @replacements = (
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/<[^>]+>/ /g; },
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/\s+/ /g; },
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/[\(\{\[]\d+[\(\{\[]/ /g; },
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/\s+[<>]+\s+/\. /g },
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/\s+/ /g; },
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/\.*\s*[\*|\#]+\s*([A-Z\"])/\. $1/g; },
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/\.\s*\([^\)]*\) ([A-Z])/\. $1/g; }
);

# Assume your data is in $_
foreach my $repl (@replacements) {
    &{$repl}($_);
}
```

You could of course use a hash instead with some more useful key as the hash, and/or you could use multivalued elements (or hash values) including comments or other information.

Comment: /e and /ee are safer than string eval

Comment: @Chas: Definitely prettier in this case, but how are they safer?

Comment: But I like the subroutine version.

Comment: Hmm, I know /e is safer because it is more like eval {} than eval "", but /ee may not be safer, but I can't remember why.

Comment: /e is just a string eval. /ee is the same thing, but you take the result of the first /e and do it again. There isn't a safety feature by adding or subtracting an /e.

Comment: I really like John Siracusa's edit, suggesting using "for ($mystr) { ... }" as a way to "topicalise" -- neat!

Answer (score 4):

Hashes are not good because they are unordered.  I find an array of arrays whose second array contains a compiled regex and a string to eval (actually it is a double eval) works best:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @replace = (
    [ qr/(bar)/ => '"<$1>"' ],
    [ qr/foo/   => '"bar"'  ],
);

my $s = "foo bar baz foo bar baz";

for my $replace (@replace) {
    $s =~ s/$replace->[0]/$replace->[1]/gee;
}

print "$s\n";
```

I think j_random_hacker's second solution is vastly superior to mine.  Individual subroutines give you the most flexibility and are an order of magnitude faster than my `/ee` solution:

```
bar <bar> baz bar <bar> baz
bar <bar> baz bar <bar> baz
         Rate refs subs
refs  10288/s   -- -91%
subs 111348/s 982%   --
```

Here is the code that produces those numbers:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark;

my @subs = (
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/(bar)/<$1>/g },
    sub { $_[0] =~ s/foo/bar/g },
);

my @refs = (
    [ qr/(bar)/ => '"<$1>"' ],
    [ qr/foo/   => '"bar"'  ],
);

my %subs = (
    subs => sub {
        my $s = "foo bar baz foo bar baz";
        for my $sub (@subs) {
            $sub->($s);
        }
        return $s;
    },
    refs => sub {
        my $s = "foo bar baz foo bar baz";
        for my $ref (@refs) {
            $s =~ s/$ref->[0]/$ref->[1]/gee;
        }
        return $s;
    }
);

for my $sub (keys %subs) {
    print $subs{$sub}(), "\n";
}

Benchmark::cmpthese -1, \%subs;
```

Comment: +1. Good point about hashes being unordered -- the order of applying search & replace operations can make a big difference. I'm confused why 2 "e" flags are needed -- wouldn't one be enough? Could you step me through it?

Comment: Due to a bug in the flag evaluation portion of regexes people found that each extra e added another level of eval.  This was found to be handy, so it got promoted to a feature.  With /e the first replace becomes '<$1>', that is you see '<$1>' in $s.  The second e then evals '<$1>' producing the desired '<bar>' replacement.

Comment: You can use Tie::DxHash to maintain insertion order order: http://search.cpan.org/~kruscoe/Tie-DxHash-1.05/lib/Tie/DxHash.pm

Comment: @dinomite Yes, but at the loss of performance with no real gain in readability. This isn't really a job for a hash (keys are not randomly accessed, there is no need for unique keys, the data is not unordered, etc).  An array of coderefs seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @Chas: Thanks, but I'm wondering why you could/would not just say qr/(bar)/ => '<$1>' and then use a single /e. (I'm aware of /ee, /eee etc... so far I haven't found cause to use them but I'm on the lookout :))

Comment: @j_random_hacker because /e is evaluating $ref->[1] not the contents of $ref->[1].  The double quoted string nature of the replace is removed when you say /e.

Comment: @Chas: I see, thanks. I guess I thought Perl would treat that $ref->[1] as an expression to be interpolated without needing any /e (i.e. in the same way that a plain mention of $foo would be interpolated without /e). Oh well, cryptic Perl parsing rules 1, j_random_hacker 0...

Comment: @j_random_hacker $ref->[1] is interpolated when there is no /e, but when /e is in effect there is no interpolation step.

Comment: @Chas: I think I've finally got it -- /e implies no interpolation (like single quotes). Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @Chas.Owens: +1 for the very interresting (and quite generic) way to time and try different ways. But in general, what is, for you, the **most efficient** way (and I mean, maybe not any of those 2, as those need to call subs, which I believe adds overhead?) to do **many** search/replace in Perl? I'm writing a "colorizer" which looks for various simple-to-complex strings and adds Ansi color codes before and after each (or sometimes portions of them)... And it's sloooow when there are many search/replace or when the files to colorize gets close to several megabytes...

Answer (score 4):

You say you are dealing with HTML. You are now realizing that this is pretty much a losing battle with fleeting and fragile solutions.

A proper HTML parser would be make your life easier. [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.60/) can be hard to use but there are other very useful libraries on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) which I can recommend if you can specify *what* you are trying to do rather than *how*.

Comment: Good point, I was answering the general question of how do run multiple regexes against a string in a maintainable way, but the specific question is about running a regex on HTML, which is a no-no.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166 for why and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340 for examples on how to use HTML parsers.

Comment: That is weird, it double pasted the links, let me try again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166 for why.

Comment: HTML::Parser is often too much work for the nastiness of some data sources. If you can do a bunch of quick substitutions to regularize the input, you can make things easier down the road. This isn't a question about parsing HTML, but cleaning up dirty data.

Comment: HTML::Parser is indeed too much work in most cases. However, there are many libraries that solve many a complicated problem. I have dealt with incredibly badly formed HTML in very large files thanks to such modules. If we knew what information Jeff is trying to get out of these files, a better alternative than a massive block of substitutions with no underlying theme might present itself.