# How can I write a regular expression to capture links with no link text?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I write a regular expression to replace links with no link text like this:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com"></a>
```

with

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com">http://www.somesite.com</a>
```

?

This is what I was trying to do to capture the matches, and it isn't catching any.  What am I doing wrong?

```
string pattern = "<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\"(?<href>.*)\">\\s*</a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think you simply need to change the quantifier within the `href` group to be lazy rather than greedy.

```
string pattern = @"<a\s+href\s*=\s*""(?<href>.*?)"">\s*</a>";
```

(I've also changed the type of the string literal to use @, for better readability.)

The rest of the regex *appears* fine to me. That you're not capturing any matches at all makes me think otherwise, but there could be a problem in the rest of the code (or even the input data - have you verified that?).

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't use a regex - I'd use the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack), and a query like:

```
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[.='']")) {
    link.InnerText = link.GetAttribute("href");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

```
string pattern = "(<a\\b[^>]*href=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>)[\\s\\r\\n]*(</a>)";
```

This way also links with their `href` attribute somewhere else would be captured.

Replace with

```
"$1$2$3"
```

The usual word of warning: HTML and regex are essentially incompatible. Use with caution, this might blow up.

Answer (score 0):

[Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843993/how-can-i-write-a-regular-expression-to-capture-links-with-no-link-text/844032#844032) has the right answer, regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.