# Get "Title" attribute from html link using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex

I have the following Regex to match all link tags on a page generated from our custom cms

```
<a\s+((?:(?:\w+\s*=\s*)(?:\w+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))*?\s*href\s*=\s*(?<url>\w+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')(?:(?:\s+\w+\s*=\s*)(?:\w+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))*?)>.+?</a>
```

We are using c# to loop through all matches of this and add an onclick event to each link (for tracking software) before rendering the page content.
I need to parse the link and add a parameter to the onclick function which is the "link name".

I was going to modify the regex to get the following subgroups

- The title attribute of the link
- If the link contains an image tag get
  the alt text of the image
- The text of the link

I can then check the match of each subgroup to aqquire the relevant name of the link.

How would I modify the above regex to do this or could I achieve the same think using c# code?

Comment: You are using ASP.NET to generate this page?

Comment: WOuld some kindly mod please add this to the FAQ at some point?

Comment: Yes I am using ASP.NET to generate the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

In particular you may be interested in the [HTMLAgilityPack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773769#773769).

Comment: Yes I can see that regex isn't particularly great at parsing html, which I why (as well as my lack of regex knowledge) I am struggling with this.

Bearing in mind I can't guarantee this app has xhtml can you reccomend a good c# parser that would achieve the above?

Comment: Sorry missed your anchor to the HTMLAgilityPack,  ill take a look, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("<a[^>]*?title=\"([^\"]*?\"[^>]*?>");
```

A couple of gotchas:

- This will match is case-sensitive, you may want to adjust that
- This expects the title attribute both exists and is quoted

  - Of course, if the title attribute doesn't exist, you probably don't want the match anyway?

To Extract, use the groups collection:

```
reg.Match("<a href=\"#\" title=\"Hello\">Howdy</a>").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do want to match if no title tag is present the content in this particular cms is very poor quality html so If title isn't present I need to check image alt then link text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chaos. Owens for pointing me towards the HtmlAgilityPack library its great.  in the end I used it to sort out my problem as below.
I would defiantly recommend this library to others.

```
   HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmldoc.LoadHtml(content);
    HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
    if (linkNodes != null)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
        {
            string linkTitle = linkNode.GetAttributeValue("title", string.Empty);
            //If no title attribute exists check for an image alt tag
            if (linkTitle == string.Empty)
            {
                HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("img[@alt]");
                if (imageNode != null)
                {
                    linkTitle = imageNode.GetAttributeValue("alt", string.Empty);
                }
            }
            //If no image alt tag check for span with text
            if (linkTitle == string.Empty)
            {
                HtmlNode spanNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("span");
                if (spanNode != null)
                {
                    linkTitle = spanNode.InnerText;
                }
            }

            if (linkTitle == string.Empty)
            {
                if (!linkNode.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    linkTitle = linkNode.InnerText;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this, though I don't think it was intended: *"I would **defiantly** recommend this library to others."*