# Using regex to grab text between multiple lines

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to grab the word Juwelier that is before the  tag from this HTML page code.

I am not very good with RegEx, and especially not with using it on multiple lines.
Thing that will NOT be dynamic :

- `<p>Rubriek:`
- `class="category"`
- and ofcourse the html tags like `<p> , </p> , <a> , </a>`

This is the HTML page code

```
    <p>Rubriek: 

      <a href="http://www.detelefoongids.nl/juwelier/4-1/?oWhat=Juwelier"
         title="Juwelier"
         class="category">
           Juwelier
      </a>
   </p>
```

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935918/php-substring-extraction-get-the-string-before-the-first-or-the-whole-strin?rq=1

Comment: @PHPNooB - I don't think so. This is a VB.NET application, so the regex and the code will be different.

Comment: Please consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for tasks like this. Regex are ill-suited (harder to implement and much harder to maintain).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get "Title" attribute from html link using Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853388/get-title-attribute-from-html-link-using-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regex below is one among many that you could use.
It uses zero-width positive look-behind `(?<=)` and look-ahead `(?=)` assertions to locate the target string.

```
Dim str As String = _
"<p>Rubriek:" & vbCrLf &
"  <a href=""http://www.detelefoongids.nl/juwelier/4-1/?oWhat=Juwelier""" & vbCrLf &
"     title = ""Juwelier""" & vbCrLf &
"     class=""category"">" & vbCrLf &
"       Juwelier" & vbCrLf &
"  </a>" & vbCrLf &
"</p>"

Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(str, _
    "(?<=<p>Rubriek:[^>]+?class=""category"">\W*)\w+(?=\W*</a>)")

If (match.Success) Then
    MsgBox(match.Value)
End If
```

Although not used above, an important thing to remember when trying to match over multiple lines is to use Single-line mode if you are going to use the wild-card metacharacter `.`, so that it matches every character *including new-lines*. This can be specified using `RegexOptions.Singleline` or by putting `(?s)` at the start of the Regex.

`\w+` is used to match one or more word characters, i.e. `a-zA-Z0-9_`
`\W*` is used to match zero or more non-word characters.
`[^>]` is used to match characters that are not `>`.