# How to Find Quotes within a Tag?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, tags, quotes

I have a string like this:

`This <span class="highlight">is</span> a very "nice" day!`

What should my RegEx-pattern in VB look like, to find the quotes within the tag? I want to replace it with something...

`This <span class=^highlight^>is</span> a very "nice" day!`

Something like <(")[^>]+> doesn't work :(

Thanks

Comment: Which regular expression engine are you using?

Comment: html grammar is not regular grammar use an html parser etc etc etc etc

Comment: Hi, I am using the engine provided by vb, so lookbehind is not supported.

Comment: @Moo The language you are using is one of the more important tags since it will prevent people from telling you how to do things you can't do and makes sure that people who know about your environment see your question.  I have replaced the pattern tag with vb, please edit it so it reflects the version of vb you are using.

Comment: @Moo VB.Net does support look behind you just use a group starting with ?<=. So (?<=X). matches any character with an X infront.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on your regex flavor, but this works for most of them:

```
"(?=[^<]*>)
```

**EDIT:** For anyone curious how this works. This translates into English as "Find a quote that is followed by a > before the next <".

Comment: Note that the plain `>` character is allowed in attribute values.

Comment: @Gumbo Interesting note but the '>' character will not be a problem if it appears in an attribute. The '<' character however will be.

Comment: @Nick The pattern has problems, if the string looks like: This "is" > great! How can we improve it?

Comment: @Moo, the '>' character is not valid have between tags. It needs to be escaped as '&gt;'. But if you need to be that picky, you need to get a real HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

If you are using VB.net you should be able to use [HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773769#773769).

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `<span class="([^"]+?)?">`

Answer (score -1):

This should get your the first attribute value in a tag:

```
<[^">]+"(?<value>[^"]*)"[^>]*>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to replace ALL quotation marks within tags, you could use the following regular expression:

`(<[^>"]*)(")([^>]*>)`

That will isolate the substrings before and after your quotation mark. *Note that this does not attempt to match opening and closing quotation marks. It simply matches a quotation mark within a tag.*

Comment: Yes, my intention is to replace all quotation marks within tags. Do I have to loop through all submatches then?

Comment: So, are you able to use Regex.Replace? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'd use the replace function. But I don't know how to use it with the pattern. It doesn't find the quotes within a tag.