# regex for changing height and width value in an embed code

Tags: javascript, regex, embed

HI

I have an application where users can paste their embed code.While displaying I want to change the height and width of the embed code to a fixed value of my choice. Can you tell me the regular expression to find the width and height in the embed code. width="300" height="500". I want to be able to get these two values completely so that I can replace them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following examples take into account the ordering, what quotations are used, and if people put in spaces

A straight replace:

```
embeddedString = embeddedString.replace(/(width\s*=\s*["'])[0-9]+(["'])/ig, $1 + yourWidth + $2);
embeddedString = embeddedString.replace(/(height\s*=\s*["'])[0-9]+(["'])/ig, $1 + yourHeight + $2);
```

Or to transform the width:

```
embeddedString = embeddedString.replace(/width\s*=\s*["']["']/ig, function($0, $1)
{
    return $1 * 2;
});
```

if you actually want to remove the whole thing, but use the values:

```
var originalWidth;
var originalHeight;
embeddedString = embeddedString.replace(/(?:width|height)\s*=\s*["']([0-9]+)["']\s*(?:width|height)\s*=\s*["']([0-9]+)["']/ig, function($0, $1, $2, $3, $4)
{
    // $0 = original string
    // $1 = either 'width' or 'height'
    // $2 = the value of width or height, depending on above
    // $3 = either 'width' or 'height'
    // $4 = the value of width or height, depending on above
    // here you might want to set another value, eg:
    originalWidth = $2;
    return "";
});
```

Comment: Thanks Luke
But when I use ur code as below:
function change()
    {
    var embeddedString=document.getElementById("Text1").value;
     embeddedString = embeddedString.replace('/(width\s*=\s*[\"])[0-9]+([\"])/ig', 'width="500"');
    document.getElementById("Text2").value=embeddedString;
    }

It doesn't replace any values. I am writing the code in javascript. Am I doing any mistake?. Please correct it.

Comment: Hi mini, do it without the quotes around the regular expression - the //ig syntax is a special syntax for compiled regex'

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

You may be interested into the two answers related to JavaScript: [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773978#773978) and [DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773894#773894).

Comment: +1 For mentioning the use of an appropriate parser. But is it possible to use the jQuery/DOM without having the external ressources being loaded automatically?

Comment: @Gumbo The DOM is part of the web browser, so it should already be waiting for you.

Comment: except that they paste the code in so there is no interpretation into a dom by the browser

Answer (score 0):

This one does it:

```
width="(.*?)" height="(.*?)"
```

and grab the first and second values. What language are you using? The implementation might be different.

In PHP:

```
     $pattern = '/width="(.*?)" height="(.*?)"/';
     $subject = 'width="500" height="300"';

     preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

     print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I want to write it in javascript

Comment: Not sure about javascript, but if you can read the PHP code above, you can use the info here to translate it:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html