# remove xml declaration from xml Data using perl or awk

Tags: xml, perl, awk, xml-serialization, xml-declaration

Our application is at the receiving-end to do retro-analysis of XML data. Our application doesn't have Java or .NET available, but runs in Unix, so it has awk and Perl.

The XML messages in the file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

I tried a few options in Perl and awk to get them removed, but couldn't get these to work:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>//g"  inputFile
perl -p -i -e "s/<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>//g"  inputFile
perl -p -i -e "s/<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" \?>//g"  inputFile
```

Any other option to do this using PERL or AWK?

Comment: Are you using an XML parser when "receiving" the XML? The XML declaration is useful for a parser, and trying to process any significant XML with anything but a parser will lead to madness. And, if you're on Unix, you have all sorts of languages available to you, if you install them.

Comment: Take a look at "[How can I mine an XML document with awk, Perl, or Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/909076/128421)" for a related answer.

Comment: Your Perl code isn't working because `?` is a regular expression metacharacter. Replace the `?` with `.` or `\?` in each case and you should be OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are right. But i tried perl -p -i -e "s/<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" \?>//g" inputFile , but still not working. I will add into the main question

Comment: Oops - I did not notice that you'd enclosed the `-e` in double quotes; I'd automatically use single quotes.  This worked for me: `perl -p -e 's/<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" \?>//g'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me without overwriting the data file:

```
perl -p -e 's/<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" \?>//g'
```

I'd only overwrite the file (`-i`) when I was sure I'd got the basic regex working without doing damage.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to match the whole string if your file is XML. `<?xml version` is enough.

Try:

```
sed -i '/<\?xml version/d' file
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
foo
bar
xyz
hello
there'|sed '/<\?xml version/d' 
foo
bar
xyz
hello
there
```

Comment: @above, it didn't work.  "sed: illegal option -- i".   I tried without "-i" option, but it truncated the message incorrectly.

Comment: @diaryfolio see the test in answer, it did give what you want, didn't it?

Comment: `$ cat inputFile.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><WEEKDAY><day>Monday<day></WEEKDAY>`
`$ cat inputFile.xml | sed '/<\?xml version/d'`
`$`
Seems like its truncating whole of the message