# Using regular expression to trim html

Tags: c#, html, regex

Been trying to solve this for a while now.

I need a regex to strip the newlines, tabs and spaces between the html tags demonstrated in the example below:

Source:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>
           Some title
       </title>
    </head>
</html>
```

Wanted result:

```
<html><head><title>Some title</title></head></html>
```

The trimming of the whitespaces before the "Some title" is optional.
I'd be grateful for any help

Comment: How do you know what white space to remove? Why are you removing the white space *around* "Some title", but not *in* it? What are your rules here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s/\s*(<[^>]+>)\s*/\1/gs`

or, in c#:

`Regex.Replace(html, "\s*(<[^>]+>)\s*", "$1", RegexOptions.SingleLine);`

Comment: the first character cannot be a space, or a valid HTML string like "if a < 3 and b > 4" would be deleted with your expression

Comment: And you don't match ending tags </xxx> either.

Comment: Your first point isn't wrong, though.  That'll change "if a < 3 and b > 4" to "if a<3 and b>4", which is probably OK if that's script, but probably not desirable if it's, say, the text of an article about using whitespace for readability.

Comment: Yeah the <[^>]+> to match all html tag innards has a number of edge cases. There are more complete patterns that could be used instead of that subpattern, but this demonstrates the basic idea.

Answer (score 20):

If the HTML is strict, load it with an XML reader and write it back without formatting. That will preserve the whitespace within tags, but not between them.

Comment: Not to mention it doesn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: that might depend on the schema.  Preservation of whitespace inside tags is a specific attribute in schema definitions.

Comment: This.  Trying to parse xml/html/other CFLs with a regular expression is impossible to do 100% correctly.

Answer (score 1):

\d does not match only [0-9] in Perl 5.8 and 5.10; it matches any UNICODE character that has the digit attribute (including "\x{1815}" and "\x{FF15}").  If you mean [0-9] you must either use [0-9] or use the bytes pragma (but it turns all strings in 1 byte characters and is normally not what you want).

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

You may find the [HTMLAgilityPack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/773769#773769) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s/[^\w\/\d<>]+/gs
```

Answer (score 0):

`s/>\s+</></gs`

Answer (score 0):

This removes the whitespace between tags and the space between the tags and the text.

```
s/(\s*(<))|((>)\s*)/\2\4/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(input, "<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with XSLT would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">    
<xsl:output  method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- trim whitespaces from the content -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <!-- remove from tag to content -->
    <xsl:variable name="trimmedHead" select="replace(.,'^\s+','')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="trimmed" select="replace($trimmedHead,'\s+$','')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$trimmed"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- do not trim where text content exist -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:if test="not(matches(.,'^\s+$'))">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You can choose the template you would like to use. The first removes all whitespaces also when content exists, and the second one removes only when there are just whitespaces or newlines.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to preserve the new lines, since the removal of newlines was messing up my html. So I went with the following. .

```
private static string ProcessHTMLFile(string input)
{
    string opt = Regex.Replace(input, @"(  )*", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    opt = Regex.Replace(opt, @"[\t]*", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    return opt;
}
```