# How do I remove whitespace in HTML Source with Html Agility Pack and C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Before posting I tried the solution from this thread:

[C# - Remove spaces in HTML source in between markups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691767/c-sharp-remove-spaces-in-html-source-in-between-markups)

Here is a snippet of the HTML I'm working with:

```
<p>This is my text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>This is next text</p>
```

I'm using HTML Agility Pack to clean up the HTML:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(htmlLocation);
foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").ToList())
{
    if (item.InnerHtml == "&nbsp;")
    {
        item.Remove();
    }
}
```

The output of the code above is

```
<p>This is my text</p>





<p>This is next text</p>
```

So my problem is how do I remove the extra whitespace between the two paragraphs in the HTML source.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how your code outputs the result after your `foreach` loop.

Comment: Removal of nodes from collection used in foreach usually leads to problems and exceptions - please check if you get any exceptions

Comment: Hi good day, It didn't received any error message. Thank you.

Comment: You are removing the entire items, mean node `<p>`. What you should do is `item.InnterHtml=string.Empty`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the text nodes between the first and last paragraphs:

HTML:

```
var html = @"
<p>This is my text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>This is next text</p>";
```

Parse it:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var paragraphs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").ToList();
foreach (var item in paragraphs)
{
    if (item.InnerHtml == "&nbsp;") item.Remove();
}
var followingText = paragraphs[0]
    .SelectNodes(".//following-sibling::text()")
    .ToList();
foreach (var text in followingText) 
{
    text.Remove();
}
```

Result:

`<p>This is my text</p><p>This is next text</p>`

If you want to keep the line break between the paragraphs, use a `for` loop and call `Remove()` on all *except* the **last** text node.

```
for (int i = 0; i < followingText.Count - 1; ++i)
{
    followingText[i].Remove();
}
```

Result:

```
<p>This is my text</p>
<p>This is next text</p>
```