# remove html element from the template in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

My JSON response is something like this:

```
{
          "description": "discription about the feaure will come here.  <a href=\"http://example.com\" target=\"_blank\">Learn more</a>",
          "largeIconURL": "some_path/ico_someicon.gif",
          "displayName": "feature one"
        },
        {
          "description": "discription about the feaure will come here.",
          "largeIconURL": "some_path/ico_someicon.gif",
          "displayName": "feature two"
        },
        {
          "description": "discription about the feaure will come here. ",
          "largeIconURL": "some_path/ico_someicon.gif",
          "displayName": "feature three"
        },
```

My template is something like this

```
<%
        _.each(items,function(item, key, list){
      %>
      <li>
        <div class="oneSpec">

          <div class="description">
            <h4><%= item.displayName %></h4>
            <p><%= item.description %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <%
        });
      %>
```

How can i remove the anchor tag from `description` node before painting it to the DOM

Comment: To remove _description_ definitely not write it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "from description", but you can conditionally include something by using `<% if (condition) {%>`. I'm just guessing what you mean. If this is not it, you have to be more clear...

Update:

Remove the anchor like so ([Regex in Javascript to remove links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960156/regex-in-javascript-to-remove-links)):

```
<%=item.description.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i,"")) %>
```

Comment: one of my json node contains an <a> tag in it. I want to remove it.

 `"description": "discription about the feaure will come here.  <a href=\"http://example.com\" target=\"_blank\">Learn more</a>",`

Comment: Check out this answer to remove links from a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960156/regex-in-javascript-to-remove-links You can do all of this in the template or clean the json before passing it into the template.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is :
After Rendering,
Use

---

$(".description p a").remove(); //using jquery