# How to remove hyper link from html method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please walk through below code and help me, how to remove hyper link from html method.
I want final output in HTML format in footercontent variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var footercontent = $('footer').html();
        alert(footercontent); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <footer>
        <a href="#">Site Map</a> | <a href="#">Privacy statement</a> | <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <p>Fotoer contetn 1</p>
        <p>Footer content 2</p>
        <p>Footer content 3</p>
        <p>Footer content 4</p>

    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to make the links just text, or completely remove the existence of the links?

Comment: Yes I want those links just text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$("footer > a").replaceWith(function(){
    return $( this ).contents();
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vypohcsz/7/)

Comment: A lot better than the original answer you had.

Comment: @epascarello original answer was cause i thought he want to remove `a` element.

Comment: Hi Alex 
I want this final out in one variable with same format. I will use that variable in print functionality

Answer (score 1):

Loop through and use replaceWith or use the function in replaceWith

```
$("a").each(
    function() {
         var anc = $(this);
         anc.replaceWith(anc.text());   
    }
);
```

Answer (score -3):

Regex is what you need...

Taken from [Regex in Javascript to remove links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960156/regex-in-javascript-to-remove-links)

```
  mystr = "check this out <a href='http://www.google.com'>Click me</a>. cool, huh?";
alert(mystr.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i,""));
```

Comment: You should add comment to mark the question as duplicate...

Comment: You should never use a regular expression on HTML