# How to replace string from a particular index to end

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to replace a string from a particular index to end

I have different string inputs with a link at the end I want to delete that link

for example I have :

> Hello world ! this is my website link http://www.lo.com

I want to delete the link to get only :

> Hello world ! this is my website link

Code :

```
Var message = "Hello world ! this is my website link http://www.lo.com";
```

How to do that in Javascript ?

Comment: Try to explore the power of regular expressions https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex in Javascript to remove links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960156/regex-in-javascript-to-remove-links)

Comment: To clarify, you want the (text you have presented + the link address) to show only and the link itself to be disabled?

Comment: @MikeHorstmann I think the question is very clear.. there is no disabled link needed as you can see in the wanted result..

Comment: Have a look at `indexOf` and `substr` or `substring`

Comment: @MateiMihai If the question was that clear, why would the OP not just change the variable to exclude the website link?

Comment: @MikeHorstmann are you serious with that question? That text might come from an user input..

Comment: @MateiMihai Exactly, I don't know but thank you though for answering the question to the O.P. that was super helpful for me.  Please, stop turning Stack into a "You're wrong, your train of thought is wrong" type of community.  We're supposed to be here to help each other not be condescending.  I could REALLY be condescending with a lot of the outsourced code I have to spend my entire day rewriting that was written assumption driven people like you.  Make helpful comments or just don't respond to people who didn't post the question your kind are ruining Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "Hello world ! this is my website link http://www.lo.com";

var idx = str.indexOf("http://");

str = str.slice(0,idx-1);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do this:

```
message = message.substring(0, message.lastIndexOf("http://www.lo.com"));
```

(obs: use `substring` instead of `substr` because `substr` is [deprecated now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr))

Or if you want something more general, like removing all hyperlinks at the end of the message:

```
message = message.replace(/(\s*(http|https):\/\/.*$)/,"");
```

Have fun.

Comment: Today `substr` is deprecated and you have a problemas in some browsers. Is more safe using `substring`
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeLinks(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, ' '); // replacing with space
}

var text = "Hello world ! this is my website link http://www.lo.com";
var corrected = removeLinks(text);
alert(corrected);
```

Just call the function removeLinks() which strips off the web links