# How to change this regex to properly extract tag attributes - should be simple

Tags: java, regex

I need to "grab" an attribute of a custom HTML tag. I know this sort of question has been asked many times before, but regex really messes with my head, and I can't seem to get it working.

A sample of XML that I need to work with is

`<!-- <editable name="nameValue"> --> - content goes here - <!-- </editable> -->`

I want to be able to grab the value of the name attribute, which in this case is nameValue. What I have is shown below but this returns a null value.

My regex string (for a Java app, hence the \ to escape the ") is: 
     `"(.)?<!-- <editable name=(\".*\")?> -->.*<!-- </editable> -->(.)?"`

I am trying to grab the attribute with quotation marks I figure this is the easiest and most general pattern to match. Well it just doesn't work, any help will help me keep my hair.

Comment: The HTML comments are there for good reason. I don't want the browser to show the <editable> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the `(.)?`s at the beginning and end of your regex. And you need to put in a capturing group for getting only the content-goes-here  bit:

This worked for me:

```
String xml = "RANDOM STUFF<!-- <editable name=\"nameValue\"> --> - content goes here - <!-- </editable> -->RANDOM STUFF";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!-- <editable name=(\".*\")?> -->(.*)<!-- </editable> -->");
Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("no match found");
}
```

This prints:

```
 - content goes here -
```

Answer (score 2):

Your search is [greedy](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Greedy.html). Use `"\<\!-- \<editable name=\"(.*?)\"\> --\>.*?\<\!-- \<\/editable\> --\>"` (added `?`). Please note that this one will not work correctly with nested `<editable>` elements.

If you don't want to perform syntax checking, you could also simply go with: `"\<\!-- \<editable name=\"(.*?)\"\> --\>"` or even `"\<editable name=\"(.*?)\"\>"` for better simplicity and performance.

**Edit:** should be

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile( "\\<editable name=\"(.*?)\"\\>" );
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. What are the \ for in \?\> -- why would you escape the ? and > characters?

Comment: Because those characters can be special characters in a regex. The ? is incorrect though, removed it. And actually in a Java string, I should escape the backslash as well => \\>.

Comment: '<', '>' and '!' don't need to be escaped.

Comment: ! is used in negative look-ahead pattern and < in look-behind. Indeed, > does not need to be escaped (yet). But it doesn't harm AFAIK, so I often do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I use JavaScript, but it should help to make the expression non-greedy where possible and use not matches instead of any character matches.  Not sure how similar regexps are with Java, but instead of using the expression `\".*\"` try using `\"[^\"]*\"`.  That will search for any character within the attribute value that isn't a quote, meaning the expression can't match beyond the attribute value.

Hope that helps

Comment: +1 for the not-quotes approach. FYI, Java regexes can do everything the JavaScript flavor can, plus a lot more.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I know Javascript's regexes are lacking in some areas lookbehinds, for example.  Hopefully that will improve in time.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

You may find the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/774519#774519) using [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) helpful.