# Regex, match newlines between tags

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex in PHP:

```
preg_match('/\[summary\](.+)\[\/summary\]/i', $data['text'], $match);
```

It works fine when the text between the summary tags is on one line. However, when it contains newlines, it doesn't match.

I've tried to find a correct modifier here: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
But the only one related to newlines is "m" and that doesn't do what I want.

How to make this work?

Comment: Note that your regular expression will match [summary], then match to the end of the string, and then backtrack until it finds [/summary]. What you probably want is for it to stop matching after the first [/summary] after [summary]. The easiest way to do so is to use a non-greedy quantifier: (.+?)

Comment: There will only be one set of summarry tags, and it will only be written by administrators, so it doesn't really matter here. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page you've linked to describes another options that has an effect on how line breaks are handled.

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>     If this modifier is set, **a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines**. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

You may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/774853#774853) that uses [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) helpful.