# How do I replace multiple words, each hashed to an alternate word, in a HTML attribute using Perl regex?

Tags: html, css, perl, obfuscation

I'm writing an HTML obfuscator, and I have a hash correlating user-friendly names (of ids and classes) to obfuscated names (like a,b,c,etc). I'm having trouble coming up with a regexp for accomplishing replacing something like

```
<div class="left tall">
```

with

```
<div class="a b">
```

If tags could only accept one class, the regexp would simply be something like

```
s/(class|id)="(.*?)"/$1="$hash{$2}"/
```

How should I correct this to account for for multiple class names within quotes? Preferrably, the solution should be Perl compatible.

Comment: Some might say `left` and `tall` are just as obfuscated as `a` and `b`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess I'd do this:

```
s/  
    (class|id)="([^"]+)"
/   
    $1 . '="' . (
        join ' ', map { $hash{$_} } split m!\s+!, $2
    ) . '"'
/ex;
```

Comment: What do you do when the text of the HTML contains class="foo"?  Single regexes/substitutions don't mix well with recursively structured data.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using a regex for this in the first place.  You are trying to do too much with one regex (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

Take a look at [`HTML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm).  Here is a, probably incomplete, implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Parser;

{
    my %map = (
        foo => "f",
        bar => "b",
    );

    sub start {
        my ($tag, $attr) = @_;
        my $attr_string = '';
        for my $key (keys %$attr) {
            if ($key eq 'class') {
                my @classes = split " ", $attr->{$key};
                #FIXME: this should be using //, but
                #it is only availble starting in 5.10
                #so I am using || which will do the
                #wrong thing if the class is 0, so
                #don't use a class of 0 in %map , m'kay
                $attr->{$key} = join " ", 
                    map { $map{$_} || $_ } @classes;
            }
            $attr_string .= qq/ $key="$attr->{$key}"/;
        }

        print "<$tag$attr_string>";
    }
}

sub text {
    print shift;
}

sub end {
    my $tag = shift;
    print "</$tag>";
}

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
    start_h => [ \&start, "tagname,attr" ],
    text_h  => [ \&text, "dtext" ],
    end_h   => [ \&end, "tagname" ],
);

$p->parse_file(\*DATA);

__DATA__
<html>
    <head>
        <title>foo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="foo">Foo!</span> <span class="bar">Bar!</span>
        <span class="foo bar">Foo Bar!</span>
        This should not be touched: class="foo"
    </body>
</html>
```