# php - why does this regex truncate my string to zero length?

Tags: php

Yesterday I tracked down a strange bug which caused a website display only a white page - no content on it, no error message visible.

I found that a regular expression used in preg_replace was the problem.

I used the regex in order to replace the title html tag in the accumulated content just before echo´ing the html. The html got rather large on the page where the bug occured (60 kb - not too large) and it seemed like preg_replace / the regex used can only handle a string of certain length - or my regex is really messed up (also possible).

Look at this sample program which reproduces the problem (tested on PHP 5.2.9):

---

```
function replaceTitleTagInHtmlSource($content, $replaceWith) {
  return preg_replace('#(<title>)([\s\S]+)(<\/title>)#i', '$1'.$replaceWith.'$3', $content);
}


$dummyStr = str_repeat('A', 6000);

$totalStr = '<title>foo</title>';

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $totalStr .= $dummyStr;
}

print 'orignal: ' . strlen($totalStr);
print '<hr />';

$replaced = replaceTitleTagInHtmlSource($totalStr, 'bar');

print 'replaced: ' . strlen($replaced);
print '<hr />';
```

Output:

orignal: 60018
**replaced: 0**

So - the function gets a string of length 60000 and returns a string with 0 length. Not what I wanted to do with my regex.

---

Changing

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
```

to

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
```

in order to decrease the total string length, the output is:

orignal: 6018
replaced: 6018

---

When I removed the replacing, the content of the page was displayed without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're running into the [backtracking limit](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit).

This is confirmed if you print [`preg_last_error()`](http://php.net/preg_last_error): it returns `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR`.

You can either increase the limit in your ini file or using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set) or change your regular expression from `([\s\S]+)` to `.*?`, which will stop it from backtracking so much.

Comment: `([\s\S]+?)` is non-greedy too - but `([^<]+)` is better stops at first `<` and can't go any further.  `<title>` doesnt allow tags anyway...

Answer (score 1):

It thas been said many times before on SO, eg [Regex to match the first ending HTMl tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458280/regex-to-match-the-first-ending-html-tag) (and probably will be mentioned again) that regexes are not appropriate for HTML because tags are too irregular.

Use DOM functions where they're available.

Answer (score 1):

Backtracking:  `[\s\S]+` will match ALL available characters, then go backwards through the string looking for the `</title>`.   `[^<]+` matches all characters that aren't `<` and therefore grabs `</title>` faster.

```
function replaceTitleTagInHtmlSource($content, $replaceWith) {
  return preg_replace('#(<title>)([^<]+)(</title>)#i', '$1'.$replaceWith.'$3', $content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to be a little funny.

([\s\S]+) matches all space and non-space. you should try (.*?) instead.

changing your function works for me:

```
function replaceTitleTagInHtmlSource($content, $replaceWith) {
  return preg_replace('`\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>`i', '<title>'.$replaceWith.'</title>', $content);
}
```

and the problem seems to be you trying to use $1 and $3 to match  and