# JavaScript lazy regex for matching HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm having a problem writing a regular expression for matching HTML tags. I found a [similar entry here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458280/regex-to-match-the-first-ending-html-tag), but this didn't quite work in my case.

Here's my test string:

```
<div id="div0" class="myclass">here's some text
that may include whitespace</div><div id="div1" class="myclass">
and some more here
</div>
```

And here's my regex based on the aforementioned entry:

```
<div[^>]*class="myclass">[^~]*?<\/div>
```

Note that I need to match the first instance of `<div />` with class of "myclass." The content may have carriage returns. These `<div>` tags won't be nested.

Here's a rubular page for testing: http://rubular.com/r/vlfcikKMXk

Comment: Just thought you should know, with normal regex that *? would be helping, apparently in Ruby, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: So you already found a similar question (there are tons of them). The first answer was to use a real HTML parser, and yet you want to continue to use regular expressions for this? :)

Comment: @Kerry: You're right. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. @Lukáš Lalinský: Yes.. I have a reason not to use a parser in this case. Thanks for your 2c still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regex tested is not great. It is in fact matching as you want it to, but it is matching it multiple times (2 different matches), and not showing a difference, you only want the first match.

Go here:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Test it there, turn off the 'global' you will see it working.