# Regex not stopping on first occurrence

Tags: regex

It may sound like a duplicate thread, but I swear it isn't. I already checked other posts and found nothing useful, so here I am.

What I need to do is to isolate `<a hrefs` and take the value in between. I am able to do that with this regex:  
`(<a.*href=\"\%\(link[0-9]?[0-9]\)\".*?>(.*)?</a>)`

The text I'm trying to match is:

```
Respectively <a href="%(link3)" target="_blank">Yosuke Matsuda</a> and <a href="%(link4)" target="_blank">Kenichi Sato</a>, as <a href="%(link5)" target="_blank">boss-fights</a>
```

But this is a borderline case. Infact, it matches the whole string, just like it doesn't stop on the first occurrence of `</a>`.

I'm trying this both using Python, with this code:

```
import re

text = '''Respectively <a href="%(link3)" target="_blank">Yosuke Matsuda</a> and <a href="%(link4)" target="_blank">Kenichi Sato</a>, as <a href="%(link5)" target="_blank">boss-fights</a>'''
link_matches = re.finditer(r'(<a.*href=\"\%\(link[0-9]?[0-9]\)\".*?>(.*)</a>)', text)

try:
    for index, match in enumerate(link_matches):
        text = text.replace(match.groups()[0],
                            f'[url path="{index}"]{match.groups()[1]}[/url]')
except:
    print("no match")

print(text)
```

.. and using [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

I would expect to have this result:

```
Respectively [url path="0"]Yosuke Matsuda[/url] and [url path="1"]Kenichi Sato[/url], as [url path="2"]boss-fights[/url]
```

but what I get is:

```
Respectively [url path="0"]boss-fights[/url]
```

I have already tried moving the `?` inside the `</a>` with no luck.
Thank you in advance for the help!

Edit to re-open:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458280/regex-to-match-the-first-ending-html-tag) doesn't solve the problem. Infact, it stops only once. The result is:

```
Respectively [url path="0"]Yosuke Matsuda</a> and <a href="%(link4)" target="_blank">Kenichi Sato</a>, as <a href="%(link5)" target="_blank">boss-fights[/url].</p>
```

Comment: [parsing/matching HTML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I had to do was to add some `?`s in the regex. Like so:

```
(<a.*?href=\"\%\(link[0-9]?[0-9]\)\".*?>(.*?)</a>)
```

Comment: You may wish to consider changing `[0-9]?[0-9]` to `[0-9]+` if it's appropriate for your use-case.

`[0-9]?[0-9]` will match `link0`, `link1`, ..., `link99` but it won't match `link100`, `link101`, ....

`[0-9]+` will also match `link100` and beyond.

Comment: You could also consider using a negated character class `[^<>]` matching any character except for the angle brackets `<a [^<>]*\bhref="%\(link[0-9]{1,2}\)"[^<>]*>(.*?)</a>` See https://regex101.com/r/49vDXS/1

Comment: thank you all for the help, but still, i can't understand why my question gets closed. i even recreated the question to answer myself.. and explained why other posts don't fix it. if you are able to, please, reopen it. i will accept it as solution as soon as possible

Comment: about your suggestions: including [0-9]?[0-9] is just an overloard. it's about matching some <a hrefs in a blog article. it is impossible to have three-digit links, i'm supposed to have 10-15 max. but i can consider this. about the angle brackets, sadly i need them since i have to replace the whole group later