# RegEx to remove carriage returns between <p> tags

Tags: regex

I've stumped myself trying to figure out how to remove carriage returns that occur between `<p>` tags. (Technically I need to replace them with spaces, not remove them.)

Here's an example. I've used a dollar sign `$` as a carriage return marker.

`<p>`Ac nec `<strong>`suspendisse est, dapibus.`</strong>` Nulla taciti curabitur enim hendrerit.`$`
Ante ornare phasellus tellus vivamus dictumst dolor aliquam imperdiet lectus.`$`
Nisl nullam sodales, tincidunt dictum dui eget, gravida anno. Montes convallis`$`
adipiscing, aenean hac litora. Ridiculus, ut consequat curae, amet. Nostra`$`
phasellus ridiculus class interdum justo. `<em>`Pharetra urna est hac`</em>` laoreet, magna.`$`
Porttitor purus purus, quis rutrum turpis. Montes netus nibh ornare potenti quam`$`
class. Natoque nec proin sapien augue curae, elementum.`</p>`

As the example shows, there can be other tags inbetween the `<p>` tags. So I'm looking for a regex to replace all these carriage returns with spaces but not touch any carriage returns outside the `<p>` tags.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what tool or language do you use?

Comment: And don't forget the caveat - "<p>something <p/> something else</p>"

Comment: I'm using EditPad Pro, which I greatly enjoy to work with and clean up text. I understand having much more power in a programming language, but don't believe this is typically possible with text editors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[\r\n]+(?=(?:[^<]+|<(?!/?p\b))*</p>)
```

The first part matches one or more of any kind of line separator (`\n`, `\r\n`, or `\r`).  The rest is a lookahead that attempts to match everything up to the next closing `</p>` tag, but if it finds an opening `<p>` tag first, the match fails.

Note that this regex can be fooled very easily, for example by SGML comments, `<script>` elements, or plain old malformed HTML.  Also, I'm assuming your regex flavor supports positive and negative lookaheads.  That's a pretty safe assumption these days, but if the regex doesn't work for you, we'll need to know exactly which language or tool you're using.

Comment: Wow. That's really impressive and ugly as hell. :) I humbly confess to not being versed in lookaheads, so I'll definitely try learning more about them.

I'm also a bit embarrassed if this isn't the best tool for the job, as many have logically pointed out users a parser instead. I'm just trying to write a little macro to clean up some html output from MS Word. I believe it's a safe assumption that there will always be matching tags, never be script or sgml elements, or nested p tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A single-regex solution is basically impossible here. If you absolutely insist on not using an HTML parser, and you can count on your input being well-formed and predictable then you can write a simple lexer that will do the job (and I can provide sample code) -- but it's still not a very good idea :)

For reference:

- [Why shouldn't I parse XML or XHTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)
- [How can I parse HTML in my language of choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser)

Comment: I suggest adding links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege (reasons not to parse (X)HTML with regexes) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser (reasons to switch to your language's favorite (X)HTML parser) to your answer.

Comment: Those are nice references, better than the icenine.ca page. Added. :)

Answer (score 3):

The standard answer is: don't try to process HTML (or SGML or XML) with a regex. Use a proper parser.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are singularly unsuitable to deal with "balanced parentheses" kinds of problems, even though people persist in trying to shoehorn them there (and some implementations -- I'm thinking of very recent perl releases, for example -- try to cooperate with this widespread misconception by extending and stretching "regular expressions" **well** beyond the CS definition thereof;-).

If you don't have to deal with nesting, it's comfortably doable in a two-pass approach -- grab each paragraph with e.g. `<p>.*?</p>` (possibly with parentheses for grouping), then perform the substitution within each paragraph thus identified.

Answer (score 0):

Just use '`\n`' but ensure that you enable multiple line regex.

Comment: The question was how to match newlines only within `<p>...</p>` tags.  And there's no need to "enable multiple line regex" when you're explicitly matching `\n`.  Perhaps you meant one should apply the regex to the whole text at once rather than process it line by line?

Comment: Sorry for answering too brief, I was doing something when I was answering this. What I meant is that you can detect '`\n`' inside `&lt;p&gt;...&lt;/p&gt;` just like other characters. I have the impression that the OP knows quite a bit about RegEx except that he does not know how to match new line and he thought `$` is how to do it. Therefore, my super-quick answer is to tell him that '`\n`' can be used to match newline BUT you have to turn the multiple line regex on.

Comment: I know a decent amount about RegEx, but wasn't trying to use the $ symbol for anything other than showing where the carriage returns were (since I certainly don't know how to show a "double-stemmed" capital P).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work like this:

1. get whole paragraph (text between <p> and </p>) from teh body
2. create copy of this paragraph
3. in copy replace \n with space
4. in the body repace paragraph with modified copy

You can do it using regex, but I think simple character scanning can be used.

Some code in Python:

```
rx = re.compile(r'(<p>.*?</p>)', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

def get_paragraphs(body):
    paragraphs = []
    body_copy = body
    rxx = rx.search(body_copy)
    while rxx:
        paragraphs.append(rxx.group(1))
        body_copy = body_copy[rxx.end(1):]
        rxx = rx.search(body_copy)
    return paragraphs

def replace_paragraphs(body):
    paragraphs = get_paragraphs(body)
    for par in paragraphs:
        par_new = par.replace('\n', ' ')
        body = body.replace(par, par_new)
    return body

def main():
    new_body = replace_paragraphs(BODY)
    print(new_body)

main()
```

Comment: A respectable attempt but it will fail if someone nests P tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "almost good enough" lexing solution promised in my other answer, to sketch how it can be done. It makes a half-hearted attempt at coping with attributes, but not seriously. It also doesn't attempt to cope with unencoded "<" in attributes. These are relatively minor failings, and it does handle nested P tags, but as described in the comments it's totally unable to handle the case where someone *doesn't* close a P, because we can't do that without a thorough understanding of HTML. Considering how prevalent *that* practice still is, it's safe to declare this code "nearly useless". :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ($html !~ /\G\Z/cg) {
  if ($html =~ /\G(<p[^>]*>)/cg) {
    $output .= $1;
    $in_p ++;
  } elsif ($html =~ m[\G(</p>)]cg) {
    $output .= $1;
    $in_p --; # Woe unto anyone who doesn't provide a closing tag.
    # Tag soup parsers are good for this because they can generate an
    # "artificial" end to the P when they find an element that can't contain
    # a P, or the end of the enclosing element. We're not smart enough for that.
  } elsif ($html =~ /\G([^<]+)/cg) {
    my $text = $1;
    $text =~ s/\s*\n\s*/ /g if $in_p;
    $output .= $text;
  } elsif ($html =~ /\G(<)/cg) {
    $output .= $1;
  } else {
    die "Can't happen, but not having an else is scary!";
  }
}
```