# php regex - checking for two possible string literals values in an expression

Tags: php, regex

I am using php preg_match and I have the original expression as:

```
|(label\">Carried Price    </span> £)((.)*?)( </div)|
```

But I want to be able to able to be able to use the same basic expression but be able to search for Carried Price or Web Exclusive. I tried something like:

```
|(label\">[Carried Price|Web Exclusive]    </span> £)((.)*?)( </div)|
```

But no luck, any ideas? I also have to keep this structure of the regex as 3 groupings.

**Additional** the code I am using to test with example text

```
$page = '  <div class="web-exclusive-price">     <span class="label">Web Exclusive 
</span> £399.00 </div>
   <div class="web-only-label">     <span class="label">Offer not available in-store    </span>  </div>
    <div class="deliveryShortcut">        <span class="label"><a href="#deliverySection" onclick="navigateOpenSection(\'delivery\');">Standard Delivery</a></span> Free    </div>
';

$r = '|(label\">(?:Carried Price|Web Exclusive)    </span> £)((.)*?)( </div)|';

preg_match($r, $page, $matches);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need round braces for this. Square braces `[]` are used to specify set of characters. Here is fixed regexp:

```
$r = "'(label\">(?:Carried Price|Web Exclusive)\s+</span> £)((.)*?)( </div)'";
```

Symbol `(?:...)` means non-capturing group. Here is more information about groups http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

**Update 1:**

Also [regexp is not the best way to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Look at [allternavite way using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/774853#774853).

**Update 2 (thanks to Tim Pietzcker):**

If you're using `|` as regexp delimeter then you can't use it inside regexp. I've replaces it with `'` symbol. `\s+` is used to match any number of spaces. Now your test code is working. See example above.

Comment: Thanks for that but I've inherited a system that use this implementation, i'll definitely consider that way for next time! 
I cant seem to get the code to work as I get the error " Unknown modifier 'W' " Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to drop the `|` characters at the beginning and end of the regex. Also, there seems to be a discrepancy between whitespace in the regex and the example. I'd suggest to use `\s+` after `...Exclusive)` instead of spaces. This will also match newlines as seem to be present.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Thanks! That's the other reason. I've replaced RE delimeter this '

Comment: @tim thank you so much for the \s+ tip and the new delimiter!!! I really appreciated, its got me stomped for the past day basically!