# Regular Expression in PHP: How to create a pattern for tables in html

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am using latest PHP. I want to parse HTML page to get data.

HTML:

```
<table class="margin15" style="margin-left: 0pt; margin-right: 0pt;" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
TRs, TDs, Data
</table>

<table class="margin15" style="margin-left: 0pt; margin-right: 0pt;" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
TRs, TDs, Data
</table>

<table class="margin15" style="margin-left: 0pt; margin-right: 0pt;" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
TRs, TDs, Data
</table>

<table class="margin15" style="margin-left: 0pt; margin-right: 0pt;" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
TRs, TDs, Data
</table>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.test.com/mypage.html');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


$pattern = '/<table class="margin15" style="margin-left: 0pt; margin-right: 0pt;" width="100%" align="left" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">[^~]</table>/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

I am not able to get all tables. When I use simple **$pattern='/table/';**, it gives me exact result. How to create a pattern to get whole table at one array location?

Comment: You had better read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454, then delete your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing HTML using regex is a pain at best as HTML is not regular, I suggest you use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

[You can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but you can try:

```
$pattern = '#<table(?:.*?)>(.*?)</table>#';
```

This won't work if there are nested tables.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser/774853#774853).  It describes the usage of an HTML parser in PHP, which is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use the DOM class php offers. I think it can do the same as simple html dom but much faster (don't' get me wrong, I really like Simple Html DOM, but it's slow for files with a few dozen lines)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php is the dom class he mentions, I wasn't aware of it, but I guess it is available in core.