# Regular expression for finding class names in HTML

Tags: regex, grep

I'd like to use `grep` to find out if/where an html class is used across a bunch of files.  The regex pattern should find not only `<p class="foo">` but also `<p class="foo bar foo-bar">`.

So far I'm able to find class="foo" with this example below, can't make it work with multiple classnames:

`grep -Ern "class=\"result+(\"| )" *`

Any suggestions?  Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 17):

How about something like this:

```
grep -Erno 'class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]+"' *
```

That will also allow for more whitespace and should give you output similar to:

```
1:class="foo bar baz"
3:class = "haha"
```

To see all classes used, you can pipe output from the above into the following:

```
cut -f2 -d'"' | xargs | sort | uniq
```

Comment: The -o flag is nice. I didn't know about it--sure beats the perl command I usually use to print the match string.

Comment: Thanks Kaleb! Still wrapping my head around regex... Really like the use of the star for "zero or more" spaces or tabs... then I don't need to use those conditionals.  Very helpful.

Comment: To search for any use of a particular class (in this example "users"): `grep -Ern 'class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]*users[^"]*"' *`

Answer (score 1):

Depends what metacharacters your grep supprts, try:

'class=\"([a-z]+ ?)+\"'

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do it**.  It will drive you insane: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Instead, use a HTML parser. It's not hard.

EDIT: Here's an example in PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.html | where { 
    ([xml](Get-Content $_)).SelectNodes( '//*' ) | where { $_.GetAttribute( "class" ).Contains( "foo" ) } 
}
```

Comment: From the command line? I haven't found any yet. Care to develop one for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a pretty poor tool for parsing HTML. Try looking into simpleXML ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php ). Roll-your-own regEx on HTML is *begging* for trouble.

Comment: Find a parser e.g. here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser

Comment: This is not parsing HTML, this is pattern matching, what regular expressions where made for.

Comment: Can you post a command line example to do something similar to Kaleb's grep? What you say is the conventional wisdom, but it seems a bit over-complicated for this problem.

Comment: -1 because Mike is looking for a solution using grep and not php and this doesn't really address the question.