# Image above the title : Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am trying to display the image (with class `coreimg`) above the title on wordpress (home page and single)
`coreimg` size : fixed (eg: 680 x 240)
I know I can do some css trick by relatively aligning them but I want a more sophisticated method. I also tried `get_first_image()` method by [westondeboer](http://tipsforwordpress.com/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-post/). But the negetive point is -

- Can't fetch a specific image (with class `coreimg`), It has to be the first one.
- Its difficult to insert image's own `alt` or `title`.

So what I'm trying to do is create a wp shortcode , which would be something like :

> [coreimg src="http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/fly.jpg" title="The flying kite"]

or even the below code would be fine :

```
<img src="http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/fly.jpg" title="The flying kite" alt="The flying kite" class="coreimg"/>
```

**Update:** The problem is just fetching the image through php. And I'm unable to do it, So I started over and hoping for a kick start for the code.
  **Update2:**
Current code in `single.php`

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title();?></h1><?php the_content(); ?>
```

New Code (should be like):

```
<img src="<?php get_coreimg_url(); ?>" title="<?php get_coreimg_title(); ?>" alt="<?php get_coreimg_title(); ?>" class="headcoreimg"/>  
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title();?></h1><?php the_content(); ?>
```

Now Here I want `get_coreimg_url()`'s and `get_coreimg_title()`'s code for `functions.php`

Comment: Well, ok, you can proceed...Seioursly, your question? your solution is not working? errors? It's not very clear so far

Comment: It's still not clear on what goes wrong..I got it, it doesn't work, but how? you don't see a particular output? you get errors? you get wrong values? do you want those functions, or they're already there but not returning what you want?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I actually want the functions. :)

Comment: Well, in that case, I fear this is not the right place; people is here to help when someone has problems, or doubts, not to write code for free. You should start working on them and ask a specific question whenever you're stuck. But I believe you already knew that...

Comment: @DamienPirsy I'm not asking the code I just want to know how can I fetch the image with class `coreimg` from the content through php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. (:
Thanks everybody for helping..

So basically all you need to do is remove the default `<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title();?></h1>` from your `single.php` and/or `index.php` (for default themes)

Add the below function in `functions.php`:

```
function coreimg($atts) {
   // Just add the below shortcode in the post.
   // [cover src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/flyingkite.jpg' title='A flying Kite']
   global $post;
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('src' => '', 'title' => '' ), $atts));
   if($src == '') {
    $src = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/rotate.php';
   }
   if ($title == '') {
    $title = "{$post->post_title}";
   }
   $coverup = '<a href="';
   $coverup .= get_permalink($post->ID);
   $coverup .= '" ' . "alt='{$title}' title='{$title}' class='corecover'><img src='";
   $coverup .= "{$src}' class='cocover' alt='{$title}' title='{$title}' /></a>";
   $before = '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) .'" title="' . "{$post->post_title}\">";
   $after = '</a></h1>';
   $output = "{$coverup}{$before}{$post->post_title}{$after}";

   return $output;
}
add_shortcode('cover', 'coreimg');
```

You can grab the `random.php` file from [alistapart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/randomizer/).

## What does it do *(special)*?

If by default you haven't specified any specific image for the post it rotates random header images that you can upload in a folder (and specify in `random.php`)
. The shortcode for this might seem like `[cover title="The flying kite"]` or just `[cover]`. for complete url shortcode you can type in `[cover src="../mykite.png"]` or `[cover src="../mykite.png" title="Hey, look a kite!"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the code from get_first_image() to look for a tag with that class, instead of just the first image. You'll have to change the regex to look for class="coreimg" or something.

Comment: So what regex can I use...? Sorry but I am a newbie

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989579/regular-expression-for-finding-class-names-in-html

Also heed the warnings about using regex for html.

Comment: After some rough research - Its really not safe to use regex? Whatever but I'd just leave this method. But really thank you for the insight (: