# Get a string inside the pattern using PHP

Tags: php

I have an html file and I want to get all the classes from this file in an array using PHP. For example this is my html file:

```
<div class="main menu">element</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

I want to get an array with three elements (in this particular example):
"main", "menu", "content".

In bash it is possible to use grep to accomplish this:

```
classes=($(grep -oP '(?<=class=").*?(?=")' "./index.html"))
```

How can I do the same in PHP?

I have this basic code at this moment:

```
//read the entire string
$str = implode("", file('./index.html'));
$fp = fopen('./index.html', 'w');
//Here I guess should be the function to get all of the strings
//now, save the file
fwrite($fp, $str, strlen($str));
```

**Edit:** How can my question be the duplicate of the one provided, if I am asking on how find the string using PHP? It is not bash and I have already provided the grep alternative.

Comment: you can use regular expressions (regex)

Comment: @khuderm soo, how should I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for finding class names in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989579/regular-expression-for-finding-class-names-in-html)

Comment: Do you want `main menu`, `content` or three matches: `main`, `menu`, `content` ?

Comment: I want to get three matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the three elements, try regex [like this](https://regex101.com/r/wI1pM4/1) with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function:

```
(?:class="|\G(?!^))\s*\K[^\s"]+
```

- `\G` continues at end of the previous match or start
- `\K` resets beginning of the reported match

See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/417538)

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?:class="|\G(?!^))\s*\K[^\s"]+/', $str, $out) > 0)
  print_r($out[0]);
```

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => main
>       [1] => menu
>       [2] => content
>   )

Note that generally regex is not the appropriate means for parsing html. depends if parsing own or arbitrary html and what going to achieve imho.

Comment: parsing html with regex is foolish imo.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454.  Use DOMDocument or you may anger the gods

Comment: thanks but there are many regexers much bettter, you only would've needed to add tag 'regex' :] Also regex is generally not recommended for parsing arbitrary html.

Comment: What is the difference if it is html or not? I am editing it as a text file. I will preform the similar operations and with the files that have other extensions.

Comment: @Alex - you asked about getting classnames from an html document, which is parsing html.  there are tools for this - namely `DOMDocument`.  Learn it, use it.  Read the link i posted above - regex is great, but not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

I would use php's `DOMDocument()` class like this:

```
$classes = array();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('./index.html');
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach($elements as $element) {
    $classes = array_merge($classes,array_filter(explode(' ',$element->getAttribute('class'))));
}
print_r($classes);
```

**Explanation:**

- declare empty array `$classes`
- turn off errors DOMDocument might throw if it's incomplete or invalid html
- instantiate new `DOMDocument` object
- load file `index.html` into `DOMDocument`
- get all elements using wildcard tagname
- iterate over elements
- get classname
- explode classname by whitespace
- filter exploded array to remove empty values
- add result to `$classes` array

Comment: I agree, generally regex is not the appropriate means for parsing html :] depends if parsing own or arbitrary html and what going to achieve imho.

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer. I have made a research and found it pretty useful. I will explore this topic more. Due to the reason that I have already selected the correct answer, the only thing I can do is to up vote you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can either use regular expressions using the [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) function, or you could traverse the DOM using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.