# Regex to match html attributes

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a pattern so that I can retrieve a string from a website. Here is the string in Question:

```
<a title="Posts by ivek dhwWaVa"
href="http://www.example.com/author/ivek/"
rel="nofollow">ivek</a>
```

I am trying to match the string "ivek" in between the a tag and I want to do this for each post and **relate** it to the number of comments.

Firstly, what is the regex I should use the above so I can use it as an example for the rest. I have nothing so far:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
preg_match_all("", $content, $matches);
```

And how I would relate the comments to the authors name as there are many other authors on the website and also their own set of comments. Do I use divs to break this up? As each set of info is wrapped around this div:

```
<div id="post-54" class="excerpt">
```

Thanks all for any help!

Comment: There we go again: regex + html ... I sense a big Schloooop coming.

Comment: You are usually much better of using a XML parser *(like the DOM extension)* to work with HTML files, rather than regular expressions.

Comment: 'regex' + 'html' = red flags, whooping sirens, pleading debuggers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please let me be the first to introduce you to the [most famous answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Regular expressions are not suited to parsing HTML.  You really need an HTML parser, even for what might appear to be a simple task.

I recommend something like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Grr, I was trying to find that example :P

Comment: Ha ha, I always just google "coding horror cthulu", and get the link from Jeff's post.

Comment: God damn! Thank you very much for that. Probably should search regex + html first! :)

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't be looking to Regex to do the job:

- [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)
- [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser)

Comment: It is good (or maybe bad) to see things haven't changed a bit while I have been away and those questions are still of great use.