# Parsing XML files with regular expressions (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I am using regular expression to parse XML file (though regexp is not recommended for xml parsing, but i have to use regexp, no other go).

My doubt is how to skip commented lines in XML file, while parsing using Perl.

I want Perl to parse XML file, while skipping commented lines.

Can anyone help me, please.

Thanks 
Senthil .

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far? And why can't you use modules, such as XML::Parser (which is installed by default with ActivePerl)?

Comment: curious... why do you /have/ to use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to strip commented lines prior to parsing.

```
$string =~ s/<!--.*?-->//gs;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to strip off commented lines. I am a new bie. please

Comment: @NullUserException: Only if it's on one line. Or the file needs to be read in slurp mode.

Comment: @NullUserException: that won't help if $string has been read like `while ($string = <FILE>)`, which cuts off a line-sized chunk for reading.

Comment: @NullUserException: You'll need the /g flag too.

Answer (score 4):

As bad as this question is for many people, many answers to it are just as bad: use an XML parser, here's why, end of the discussion.

For me, the whole point of asking a question on stackoverflow is to obtain a solution. Have we provided a solution to OP? Not quite.

A more complete answer would offer some examples on how to parse xml. Here are some;

[Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser)

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is compiling XML libraries, you can try [XML::Parser::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=xml%3A%3Aparser%3A%3Alite) or [XML::Parser::PurePerl](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=xml%3A%3Aparser%3A%3Apureperl) which are pure perl modules requiring no compilation.

Or, you might be able to find pre-compiled packages of the non-pure-perl libraries. What OS are you on?

Comment: MKDoc::XML is another lightweight pure-perl XML parser which, amusingly enough, uses a monster regex as a tokenizer -- but it's the *right* regex.

Answer (score 2):

Please, [do not parse XML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), use XML parser instead.

At least you can write a simple finite-state machine based parser to process your XML. It's very simple to do it.

Comment: The OP is aware of it, but doesn't have another option

Comment: to quote op "I am using regular expression to parse XML file (though regexp is not recommended for xml parsing, but i have to use regexp, no other go)." This answer is not useful as he already knows it... bigger question is why he can't use a parser.

Comment: I understand this, but I don't understand why he *have to* use regexp.

Comment: +1 for adding the second paragraph... but i'm with all the others who say "explain why not A CPan parser".

Comment: Unless it's a homework problem, the OP *does* have other options