# Strange result on perl regexp - end string anchor & ungreedy at once

Tags: regex, perl

I have a very simple substitution:

```
my $s = "<a>test</a> <a>test</a>";
$s =~ s{ <a> .+? </a> $ }{WHAT}x;

print "$s\n";
```

that prints:

```
WHAT
```

But I was expecting:

```
<a>test</a> WHAT
```

What do I misunderstand about "end string anchor" in interaction with ungreedy option?

---

So, I was wrong about regexp engine. Indeed, dont humanize code - it doing rightly what you wrote, not you "*think do*".

Its just find first `<a>`, then find `</a>$`. First lockup are positive, pattern matched.

Right pattern must be something about:

```
$s =~ s{ <a> (?! .* <a> ) .* </a> }{WHAT}x;
```

thats give me correctly

```
<a>test</a> WHAT
```

because **now** I really asked regexp for **last** `<a>`.

I think its less efficient `[^<]+`, but more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-greedy modifier (and regexes in general) works from left-to-right, so in essence what is happening here is that it tries to find the shortest string that matches after the first `<a>` until the next `</a>` that is at the end of the string.

This does what you would expect:

```
my $s="<a>test</a> <a>test</a>";
$s =~ s#<a>[^<>]+</a>$#WHAT#;

print "$s\n";
```

What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: There's no point in using the non-greedy modifier here, because `[^<>]` can never match `<`, which is the next character in the regex.

Comment: Alternatively, only much less efficiently, `s#^.*\K<a>.*</a>$#WHAT#`; sometimes this approach is needed.

Comment: "What is the problem you're trying to solve" - I try to understood WHAT happened...

Comment: Why [^<>]+ ? Just [^<]+ to be enough.

Comment: @Meettya: yeah, `[^<]+` should be enough. I only added the other angle bracket for clarity.

Comment: @ysth: what is "\K" in s#^.*\K<a>.*</a>$#WHAT# ?

Comment: @Meettya: it's a 5.10ism; it says don't include anything before that in what part of the string is considered matched

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the reasons you don't use a regex to match HTML.  Try using a parser instead.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege) and its answers for more reasons not use a regex, and this question and its [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser) for examples of how to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes... I now about parser and regex trouble.
But!
I NEVER EVER hear about priority between 'end string anchor' and ungreedy option. Change tags to simply letter and you are haven't HTML parser anymore.
Theoretically it`s no way to chose "who is the great?", it is logical to be working:
 1. go to the END of string;
 2. find </a> tag directly at the and;
 3. find FIRST <a> tag.
I mean in thats case to be logically change 'leftmost' rule to mirrored 'rightmost'. Is`nt it?