# Is there a library for extracting data from an HTML page?

Tags: c++, html, objective-c, c, data-extraction

I would like to extract information from a web page. Unfortunately, the website (4chan) doesn't have a public API, for as far as I know.

What is a good library to extract specific data from an HTML document? I prefer a free software library that works on UNIX systems.

---

Edit: basically I want to get posts and images from 4chan. The webpage isn't valid HTML (and doesn't have a doctype) so the parser shouldn't be too strict.

Comment: Many exist. You could easily write a book on this subject. It is, after all, just XML.

Comment: @Styne HTML is not XML. Only XHTML is valid XML.

Comment: @R.Martinho For the purposes of scraping, it's much of a muchness

Comment: @Styne Yeh, appart from the fact that unless it's XHTML it's not actually valid XML so you can't use an XML parser on it...  HTML is actually a markup of SGML and there are specific HTML DOM parsers.

Comment: @Benj That depends on how strict your parser is.

Comment: @Styne - So you're suggesting that the OP find himself a particularly sloppy XML parser?  I'll be impressed if you can find one so sloppy that it'll parse a <br> without a closing tag...

Comment: @Benj Read between the lines. I'm suggesting it's not a specific enough question to have a specific answer that doesn't fill a book. There are many options for parsers depending on what type of HTML he or she is looking to scrape from. And seeing as the only clues we have are *get some kind of information out of some kind of HTML in either C, C++ or Obj-C* that's a question which needs amending.

Comment: @Styne - A general purpose HTML parser will work on any "type of HTML" and there are pleanty of HTML parser libraries which can be used from all 3 languages the OP tagged.  There's nothing wrong with asking for library recommendations although this question is a dupe of the one mentioned by Kypros.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an HTML Dom Parse.

[This link of a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser) should help you out. Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser)

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, there are lots of libraries for parsing html data. For example, if you use Perl, you can use HTML::Parse.

If you just want a fast result and you agree to use a system command you can use:

```
lynx -dump http://4chan.org
```

or

```
links -dump http://4chan.org
```

Comment: Note that the question has `c++`, `objective-c` and `c` tags when it comes to languages ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker just saw that. Sorry for being noob :)

Comment: No prob. Not my prob, for sure ;-)