# Get only text and images from <div> in Objective-C

Tags: ios, html, rss

I'm making a news reading application. The best site I found was http://fulltextrssfeed.com/
It takes the text and images from **any** webpage and gives back clean text. As they don't have an API I need some way to get the data from the `<div>`.
This is the div ID:

```
<div id="preview">
```

How can I *leach* onto the feed and get only its content (It would be a plus if there are no HTML tags, if there is I can make a work around.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a library for extracting data from an HTML page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972013/is-there-a-library-for-extracting-data-from-an-html-page)

Comment: Thats in `C++` this is Objective C

Comment: Beware, You might compromise with their copyrights. Web Scrapping should be done very cautiously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question, but if you're using obj-c, I really recommend [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). It's a really good XML/HTML parser.

To use it, you'll need to add `${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2` in "Header Search Path", in *your project option* and add `-lxml2` to "Other Linker Flag".

Then, when you already have the Hpple files, drag it to your code: `TFHpple.h`, `TFHpple.m`, `TFHppleElement.h`, `TFHppleElement.m`, `XPathQuery.h`, `XPathQuery.m`.

In the code (To get your div "preview"), add:

```
NSData *htmlData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.yoursite.com/index.html"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='preview']"]; // Here we use 
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *string = [element content];
NSLog(@"%@", string);

[xpathParser release];
[htmlData release];
```

Now we have the "preview div" with Hpple. To get some subclass (as `p` or `a`), use it:

```
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@id='preview']/p/text()"];
```

To undertand more, take a look at [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp). Also check [a tutorial](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/parsing-html-iphone-development/).

Hope it help.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but you seemed to put some good time into this so you deserve this!

Answer (score 0):

I use this to strip all html very succesfully

[NSString + Strip HTML](https://gist.github.com/1202238)