# Get video(s) location from raw HTML text

Tags: c#, html, xaml, webview, microsoft-metro

I'm loading a web page into my `WebView`, and I can access it's raw HTML as text. The page has several video elements embedded within it, and I want to get their locations as a list of strings so I can download them separately.

How would I go about doing this ?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/773769/4544845)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP agility pack for parsing

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
           document.LoadHtml(rawText);
           var videoSourceNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//video/source");
           foreach(var node in videoSourceNodes)
           {
               var path = node.Attributes["src"].Value;

           }
```

It's your concern to convert relative path to absolute.

Comment: I got the agility pack and it almost works but the `SelectNodes` function doesn't seem to be available for windows store apps.