# Removing/compacting superfluous XML/HTML tags from command line?

Tags: html, xml, formatting, pretty-print

Consider this snippet, obtained from an export:

```
<!--l. 266--><p class="indent" >
              <span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">“</span><span 
class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">Blah blah blah, </span>
              <span 
class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah blah blah, </span>
              <span 
class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah blah, blah blah blah </span>
              <span 
class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah </span>
              <span 
class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah blah, blah</span>
              <span 
class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah </span><span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">(</span><a 
href="#X0-cite"><span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">Testing </span>
              <span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">Ref, </span><a 
href="#X0-cite"><span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">1980</span></a></a><span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">, pg.1)”</span>
         </p>
```

---

EDIT: I concur with comments, that there is no general way to specify what is superfluous - this is what I meant: This code snippet is essentially meant to represent a single line as rendered HTML:

[image: firefox_html_render]

... and since all of that "bla bla..." in the content line is meant to be in the same format, I consider pieces of it carrying separate span tags that specify the same format (and indeed they are the same tags, without change in attributes, just `<span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">`) to be superfluous - even if they aren't nested.

---

Running an XML formatter/pretty printer on this (say, `xml_pp -i a.xml`) to indent our tags will result with the following code:

```
<!--l. 266--><p class="indent">
  <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">“</span>
  <span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">Blah blah blah, </span>
  <span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah blah blah, </span>
  <span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah blah, blah blah blah </span>
  <span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah </span>
  <span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah blah, blah</span>
  <span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">blah blah, blah </span>
  <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">(</span>
  <a href="#X0-cite">
    <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">Testing </span>
    <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">Ref, </span>
    <a href="#X0-cite">
      <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">1980</span>
    </a>
  </a>
  <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">, pg.1)”</span>
</p>
```

Note that here:

- we have sequences of `<span class="X">text A, </span><span class="X">text B, </span>` which are pointless, as they could be reduced to `<span class="X">text A, text B, </span>`
- We have double nested `<a href="#X0-cite">` - again pointless, could do without the inner one

Eventually, I'd like to run something, and obtain the following "compacted" code:

```
<!--l. 266--><p class="indent" >
              <span
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">“</span><span
class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">Blah blah blah,
              blah blah, blah blah blah,
              blah blah, blah blah, blah blah blah
              blah blah, blah
              blah blah, blah blah, blah
              blah blah, blah </span><span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">(<a
href="#X0-cite">
Testing
              Ref,
1980</a>
, pg.1)”</span>
         </p>
```

... where text whitespace is preserved (and individual portions of superfluous tags are removed on each line separately), and a case like `<a href="#X0-cite">` interrupting a sequence of `<span>`s is handled; which I could then prettify to:

```
<!--l. 266--><p class="indent">
  <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">“</span>
  <span class="ptmri8t-x-x-90">Blah blah blah,
              blah blah, blah blah blah,
              blah blah, blah blah, blah blah blah
              blah blah, blah
              blah blah, blah blah, blah
              blah blah, blah </span>
  <span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">(<a href="#X0-cite">
Testing
              Ref,
1980</a>
, pg.1)”</span>
</p>
```

Is there a (Linux) command line tool that could help me do the "compaction" like described? `awk` or regex scripts could do it, I guess - but it seems kinda complex for that...

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Well, technically there's nothing superfluous about these tags. Maybe *you* don't need them, but you *could* use them for something. As such there'll hardly be a specific tool to remove things *you* consider superfluous...

Comment: Many thanks for that note, @deceze - I agree, and I have now added an edit to the post, hope that clarifies - cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing prebuilt that you could use.

What you are asking for changes the DOM that would be generated from the markup. The usual case for minification seeks to change the markup without changing the model it represents.

Your white space preservation requirements are also asking for it to preserve data that doesn't expressed by the markup (since whitespace isn't collapsed except in CDATA blocks).

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Quentin - I concur with that; I wasn't thinking so much of the DOM, as much of the information needed to render the "intended output" style. Also this post: [How can I remove unused, nested HTML span tags with a Perl regex? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667130/how-can-i-remove-unused-nested-html-span-tags-with-a-perl-regex) has a bit more on similar problems, and suggestion for tools... thanks again - cheers!